# ListAGG in SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate a 'STRING' field in SQLServer. I would like to find the same function LISTAGG like in Oracle .

Do you know how to do the same function or an another method?

For Example,

```
Field A | Field B
1       |  A
1       |  B
2       |  A
```

And I would like that the result of this query will be

```
1 | AB
2 | A
```

Comment: Please add your vote for DISTINCT: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35243533-support-distinct-for-string-agg

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Starting in [SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the `STRING_AGG` function is available which simplifies the logic considerably:

```
select FieldA, string_agg(FieldB, '') as data
from yourtable
group by FieldA
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/321a3/711/1)

In SQL Server you can use `FOR XML PATH` to get the result:

```
select distinct t1.FieldA,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + t2.FieldB
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') data
from yourtable t1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/321a3/711/0)

Comment: i would like to insert an order by clause in the sub-select. Do you know how insert this clause?

Comment: @user1557642 What do you want to order?  Do you want the values reversed? You can easily add an `ORDER BY` see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0836c/7. In this case the result for `FieldA` will show `BA`

Comment: in fact i have 10 lines to aggregate. But SQLServer do a alphabatical  rank before the aggragation. I would like to aggregate with my own parameters(a third field) and not the alphabatical order.

Comment: @user1557642 You can use an `ORDER BY`, you will just have to include a `GROUP BY` in the subquery, see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0836c/7

Comment: breaks for strings with special characters like '<'; they get XML encoded.  Not a solution at all. Total hack, based on obsolete, undocumented behavior of 'for xml path'.

Comment: I don't much agree with the edit of typoerrpr, that's basically adding a new answer to an existing one. What you say Bluefeet?

Comment: @typoerrpr Feel free to add that as another answer to the question.

Comment: I had a use case where I needed pipe as the delimitter and didn't want the pipe in the beginning. To modify the above sample query to make this happen, I did:
select distinct t1.FieldA,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct '|' + t2.FieldB
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') data
from yourtable t1;

Comment: @Taryn I must disagree; I just checked the editlog for this answer and --as he described in it -- it just gives a more generic version (which makes it easier to understand/modify) of the provided snippet. If coming across that answer "twice" the viewer would likely assume it's a duplicate.

Comment: This answer is no longer good. Current versions of SQL server have STRING_AGG which does the same job and has always been faster in my tests.

Comment: @Qwertie The answer still works, but I have updated the answer to include the STRING_AGG function version as well.

Answer (score 197):

### MySQL

```
SELECT FieldA
     , GROUP_CONCAT(FieldB ORDER BY FieldB SEPARATOR ',') AS FieldBs
  FROM TableName
 GROUP BY FieldA
 ORDER BY FieldA;
```

### Oracle & DB2

```
SELECT FieldA
     , LISTAGG(FieldB, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FieldB) AS FieldBs
  FROM TableName
 GROUP BY FieldA
 ORDER BY FieldA;
```

### PostgreSQL

```
SELECT FieldA
     , STRING_AGG(FieldB, ',' ORDER BY FieldB) AS FieldBs
  FROM TableName
 GROUP BY FieldA
 ORDER BY FieldA;
```

### SQL Server

**SQL Server ≥ 2017 & Azure SQL**

```
SELECT FieldA
     , STRING_AGG(FieldB, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FieldB) AS FieldBs
  FROM TableName
 GROUP BY FieldA
 ORDER BY FieldA;
```

**SQL Server ≤ 2016 (CTE included to encourage the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))**

```
  WITH CTE_TableName AS (
       SELECT FieldA, FieldB
         FROM TableName)
SELECT t0.FieldA
     , STUFF((
       SELECT ',' + t1.FieldB
         FROM CTE_TableName t1
        WHERE t1.FieldA = t0.FieldA
        ORDER BY t1.FieldB
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS FieldBs
  FROM CTE_TableName t0
 GROUP BY t0.FieldA
 ORDER BY FieldA;
```

### SQLite

**Ordering requires a CTE or subquery**

```
  WITH CTE_TableName AS (
       SELECT FieldA, FieldB
         FROM TableName
        ORDER BY FieldA, FieldB)
SELECT FieldA
     , GROUP_CONCAT(FieldB, ',') AS FieldBs
  FROM CTE_TableName
 GROUP BY FieldA
 ORDER BY FieldA;
```

**Without ordering**

```
SELECT FieldA
     , GROUP_CONCAT(FieldB, ',') AS FieldBs
  FROM TableName
 GROUP BY FieldA
 ORDER BY FieldA;
```

Comment: great answer - a bit more concise than the marked answer + also mentions other sql dialects.  The sqlserver syntax for this is really unintuitive.  I was also surprised that the extra brackets around the select in stuff are necessary.

Comment: @manas_kumar but... why you use STUFF? it is unnecessary. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ricardo_C STUFF is being used here to remove the leading comma.

Comment: To be complete, this needs to be added to the sql server example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8856789 It prevents certain characters being replaced by XML tags.

Comment: This is great!!! ... but for some reason the `TableName` in the inner `SELECT` cannot be a CTE from the outer select. Rrgggh.

Comment: @DanLenski  That doesn't appear to be the case, as I am referencing a `cte` successfully on my other monitor right now, I would imagine you were not constructing your query correctly?

Comment: I wish if there was a version for sybase aser database though ill try to create one

Answer (score 22):

In SQL Server 2017 [STRING_AGG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx) is added:

```
SELECT t.name,STRING_AGG (c.name, ',') AS csv
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
GROUP BY t.name
ORDER BY 1
```

Also, [STRING_SPLIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) is usefull for the opposite case and available in SQL Server 2016

Comment: STRING_AGG / STRING_SPLIT were also recently added to Azure SQL Database as well for anyone that happens to land here on that platform.

Comment: Note: vNext has been named SQL Server 2017

Comment: Do you know how to use distinct c.name, so all concatenated names are unique?

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful to someone also, i.e. for data analysis and data profiling type of purposes. (i.e. not grouped by).

Prior to the SQL Server 2017 `STRING_AGG` function existing ..

(i.e. returns just one row ..)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(
        STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + [FieldB] 
            FROM tablename 
            ORDER BY 1 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        , 1, 0, '')
    , 2, 9999)
FROM tablename
```

It returns comma separated values - e.g. "A,B".