# Use listagg in SQL Server

Tags: oracle

I have the same problem with this topic [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver/19052439#19052439)

My problem is that what should I do if I want a result:

```
1 | A, B
2 | A
```

Comment: Your title and tags are mismatched; do you mean Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

From the example you show, simply add a comma to the `DISTINCT` clause, and change the `STUFF` function `start` parameter to 1 :

```
select distinct t1.FieldA,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + t2.FieldB
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') data
from yourtable t1;
```