# SQL command to merge rows with common ID?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks like:

```
Event ID  Name
1         Bob
1         Steve
1         Tom
2         Bob
3         Steve
3         Tom
```

There are thousands of event IDs, and tens of unique names. I'd like an SQL query to return the following table:

```
Event ID  Names
1         Bob, Steve, Tom
2         Bob
3         Steve, Tom
```

I'm looking for an aggregate function like `SUM()` or `AVG()` except that it joins strings instead of does mathematics.

**EDIT:** I'm stuck using MS Access on this one.

**EDIT 2:** I realize that this would be trivial in a client language, but I'm trying to see if I can get an all-SQL solution.

Comment: What kind of DBMS are you using? A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver). MySQL has `GROUP_CONCAT()`, MSSQL has `STUFF()` and Oracle has `LISTAGG()`.

Comment: are you talking about ORACLE? MySql? SqlServer? DB2?

Comment: In MSSQL, this is a pain to do, I usually end up making a CLR aggregation for concatenation.  PostgreSQL, Oracle, and MySQL do this pretty handily.

Comment: Why do you want to do that **from SQL** (instead of just using a "normal" JOIN result)? SQL is for retrieving data, not formatting. Formatting can be done easily in the client language of your choice.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Why do you say MySQL is "pain" for this - is there some problem with GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Not MySQL, MSSQL.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Oh, sorry! Long day ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which DBMS you are using but in MySQL it's pretty easy:

```
SELECT EventId, GROUP_CONCAT(Names)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY EventId
```

In SQL Server it's a little trickier.  The solution I typically see, requires that you use `FOR XML PATH`.  You can find a good article on how to do this [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=createacommadelimitedlist).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server you could do something like this

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84e12/4/0/)

```
  WITH x AS
    (
      SELECT event_id FROM users
      GROUP BY event_id
    )
    SELECT x.event_id, 
           name = STUFF((SELECT ',' + name
                         FROM users WHERE event_id = x.event_id
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    FROM x
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL this would be:

```
select EventId, string_agg(name, ',') as names
from the_table
group by EventId;
```

If you want the names sorted in the list:

```
select EventId, string_agg(name, ',' order by name) as names
from the_table
group by EventId
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; good to know that this works in PostgreSQL.