# SQL query to fetch previous record value in SQL Managment studio 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to frame a sql query for the following requirment

```
ID  |Number_flag|Active_flag_ind| Currency   |My Requirment
----|-----------|---------------|---------   -------------- 
100 | 1         |     Y         |   USD      USD-GBP
100 | 2         |     N         |   GBP      Null
201 | 1         |     N         |   AUD      AUD
```

The scenario in here is, I have two records for each `ID` and are indicated with `number_flag` and `Active_flag_ind.`

(Please refer the example above) My requirment is if I have two records for a `ID`. The `N` flags currency should be concatenated with `Y` flag currency.If I have only one ID the same records currency should be populated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post your expected output ??

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions and some logic.  If I have the logic right, it is:

1. When `number_flag = 2` then the value is `NULL`.
2. When an `id` has only one row, it will have `number_flag = 1`, then the value is `currency`.
3. When an `id` has two rows, then the one with `number_flag = 1` gets the two currencies concatenated.

The following query does this:

```
select t.id, t.number_flag, t.active_flag_ind, t.currency,
       (case when t.number_flag = 1 and
                  max(t.number_flag) over (partition by t.id) = 2
             then t.currency + '-' + max(case when t.number_flag = 2 then t.currency end) over (partition by t.id)
             when t.number_flag = 1
             then t.currency
        end) as my_requirement
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.Number_flag,
       t1.Active_flag_ind,
       CASE WHEN t1.Active_flag_ind = 'Y' AND t2.Currency IS NOT NULL
            THEN t1.Currency + '-' + t2.Currency
            WHEN t1.Active_flag_ind = 'N' AND t3.Currency IS NOT NULL
            THEN NULL
            ELSE t1.Currency
        END AS Currency
  FROM your_table t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
       your_table t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
                     AND t1.Active_flag_ind='Y'
                     AND t2.Active_flag_ind='N' LEFT OUTER JOIN
       your_table t3 ON t1.ID=t3.ID
                     AND t1.Active_flag_ind='N'
                     AND t3.Active_flag_ind='Y'
```