# duplicate entry in union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

```
1. Flat Discount
2. Promotion
3. weeklyorder
```

When i join these table and take union i got 2 row with same data but one different .. how to merge it to show only one row.

Query:

```
 SELECT skuMaster.SKU,
        (skuMaster.MinimumStock - COUNT(*)) as ReorderQuantity,
        'LowInventory' as descp
   FROM SKUMaster skuMaster
        JOIN InventoryMaster inventoryMaster ON skuMaster.SKU = inventoryMaster.SKU
  GROUP BY skuMaster.sku, skuMaster.MinimumStock, skuMaster.Name
 HAVING COUNT(*) < skuMaster.MinimumStock

  UNION

 SELECT WeeklyOrderList.SKU,
        WeeklyOrderList.Quantity as ReorderQuantity,
        'NoPO' as descp
   FROM WeeklyOrderList
  WHERE WeeklyOrderList.POCGen = 'true'
```

result :

```
SKU ReorderQuantity descp
1   1           LowInventory
2   2           LowInventory
2   2           NoPO
6   5           LowInventory
```

here 2nd And 3rd are alomost same only description is different.

can we combine them and show only one row with descp as lowinventory and NOPO

```
SKU ReorderQuantity descp
1   1           LowInventory
2   2           LowInventory NoPo
6   5           LowInventory
```

same as above suppose we have table below

SKU    ReorderQuantity 
    1   1
    2   5
    2   10
    6   5

here output should be Max reorder quantity of same sku

Result:

SKU    ReorderQuantity 
    1   1
    2   10
    6   5

Comment: _i have two tables_ `1. Flat Discount
2. Promotion
3. weeklyorder` ?

Comment: To do that, you would have to group by `SKU` and `ReorderQuantity` and aggregate the description. Some databases have `GROUP_CONCAT` or `LISTAGG`, but in SQL-Server, I think it goes like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: you are asking for other result can you please give me the clarity of output you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT skuMaster.SKU,
        (skuMaster.MinimumStock - COUNT(*)) as ReorderQuantity,
        'LowInventory' as descp
   FROM SKUMaster skuMaster
        JOIN InventoryMaster inventoryMaster ON skuMaster.SKU = inventoryMaster.SKU 
  GROUP BY skuMaster.sku, skuMaster.MinimumStock, skuMaster.Name
 HAVING COUNT(*) < skuMaster.MinimumStock

  UNION

 SELECT WeeklyOrderList.SKU,
        WeeklyOrderList.Quantity as ReorderQuantity,
        'NoPO' as descp
   FROM WeeklyOrderList 
  WHERE WeeklyOrderList.POCGen = 'true'
)

SELECT DISTINCT
       a.SKU,
       a.ReorderQuantity,
       descp = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + b.descp
                        FROM CTE b 
                       WHERE b.ReorderQuantity = a.ReorderQuantity 
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
  FROM CTE a
```

Answer (score 0):

just an  example for above output mentioned

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    SKU INT,
    ReorderQuantity INT
)

 INSERT INTO @t (SKU,ReorderQuantity)
 VALUES (1,1), (2,5), (2,10), (6,5)

 SELECT t.SKU,tt.Qty
   FROM @t t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ReorderQuantity)as Qty, SKU
                      FROM @t
                     GROUP BY SKU) tt
              ON tt.SKU = t.SKU
  GROUP BY t.SKU,tt.Qty
```