# Creating a flattened list from a rowset

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a dataset in a table. I am trying to flatten out one column so that I can see all values, delimited in one single cell. Ive tried this with hierarchies but have not been able to solve so far. Sample dataset is below.

Can anyone advise if this is possible?

```
╔════════╦════════╦═══════╦═════════════════╗
║ CaseID ║ TestID ║ Batch ║ Flattened List  ║
╠════════╬════════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ A0001  ║ T1     ║ A     ║ T1|  T1 | T2    ║
║ A0001  ║ T1     ║ B     ║ T1|  T1 | T2    ║
║ A0001  ║ T2     ║ A     ║ T1|  T1 | T2    ║
║ A0002  ║ T1     ║ A     ║ T1 | T1         ║
║ A0002  ║ T1     ║ B     ║ T1 | T1         ║
║ A0003  ║ T1     ║ A     ║ T1              ║
║ A0004  ║ T4     ║ A     ║ T4              ║
╚════════╩════════╩═══════╩═════════════════╝
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what your Flattened List field contains? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I know this is an ancient question, but do you recall what the best way was to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled many times with exactly the same issue, however I wasn't able to find an easy solution is PowerPivot. **It is certainly doable in database** (the easiest one I've ever used is [LISTAGG aggreage function](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515) available in *Oracle* / *PostgreSQL* - if that option is available). [Microsoft's SQL Server's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver) is not that sleak, but works pretty much the same way.

If you are limited to Excel, then the fastest and easiest way to do this is to use VBA macros, or simply use one of the available extensions. I personally use Excel add-on package from [AbleBits](http://www.ablebits.com/excel-combine-rows/index.php?r1=visitsite&r2=crw&r3=about) (no affiliation what-so-ever).

The *Combine Row* feature does exactly what you are asking for. It looks for unique ID (Case ID in your example) and then if there are multiple records associated with it (Test ID), it joins them into an array of values separated by your choice of delimiter.

Below is documented screen-by-screen process that shows how it transforms the data. There is a drawback though - **if your dataset is big enough (think hundred of thousand rows), then this won't be the fastest solution and I am not sure to what extent this could be automated either.**

*Data Source:*

[image]

*Combine Rows screens:*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

*And this is the end result:*

[image]