# Combine field values from different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor, aggregate

I'm searching for an intelligent method to aggregate the value of a field over different rows. Lets say this is my table:

```
ID           Value
1            TextA
1            TextB
1            TextC
2            TextA
2            TextC
```

The result I need to get would be:

```
ID           Values
1            TextA,TextB,TextC
2            TextA,TextC
```

Currently I'm working with a cursor. I think this solution is very procedural (thats where I come from) and I was wondering if there wasn't a set-theoratic solution. This is my cursor code:

```
-- Basic table containing positions
CREATE TABLE #out (id int, [values] nvarchar(1000))

INSERT INTO #out
select     1, 'TextA'
UNION ALL
select     1, 'TextB'
UNION ALL
select     1, 'TextC'
UNION ALL
select     2, 'TextA'
UNION ALL
select     2, 'TextC'

declare @id_old nvarchar(70) = NULL
declare @values nvarchar(2000) = ''
declare @id nvarchar(70)
declare @value nvarchar(50)

declare ccc cursor fast_forward for
SELECT id, [values]
from #out
order by id

open ccc

fetch next from ccc into @id, @value

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if @id_old is null
    begin
        set @id_old = @id
    end

    -- check if new id or same as previous iteration
    if @id = @id_old
    begin
        if LEN(@values) = 0
        begin
            set @values += @value -- set initial value
        end
        else
        begin
            set @values += ',' + @value -- add additional values
        end
    end

    fetch next from ccc into @id, @value

    -- when id switches update input table with collection of values
    if @id <> @id_old or @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
    begin
        update #out set [values] = @values where id = @id_old

        set @id_old = @id
        set @values = ''
    end
end

close ccc
deallocate ccc

-- since every id gets a collection of all values only keep the first entry
delete tblOut
from  (select id, [values], ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id, [values] order by id, [values]) RowNumber from #out) tblOut
where tblOut.RowNumber > 1
```

Comment: Solving this problem is actually depends of how many different VALUES for each ID do you expect to have. If you know the exact range of values, you may use PIVOT function. If you doesn't know the exact VALUES, but can predict the max number of different values - you may CROSS JOIN your table amount of times which is your max number is(has sence only for small max number <5-6). If you don't know exact range of vales or max number of values than your approach is good one OR you may use a WITH statement for creating recursion select

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID ,
       STUFF(
               (SELECT ',' + Value
                FROM myTable a
                WHERE b.ID = a.ID
                GROUP BY a.Value
                ORDER BY a.Value
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1 , 1, '')
VALUESS
FROM myTable b
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even it it seems like a cheat it works perfectly ;-)