# Find all similar combinations of two columns in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to find patterns in two columns in a very large table. My data looks like this:

```
Name | Break  
Tom  | A  
Tom  | B 
Tom  | C 
Ben  | D 
Ben  | E 
Ben  | F 
Joe  | A 
Joe  | B 
Joe  | C
```

So I want to know that Tom and Joe both shared identical breaks, "a b c" while Ben did not. I'm assuming the best format of this is to concatenate the breaks to a single record, while using group by in the name field. So my result might be:

```
Name | Group  
Tom  | ABC  
Joe  | ABC  
Ben  | DEF
```

This would allow me to use easier sql functions I am more familiar with like count() and group by. Any way to do this in access? VBA?

Comment: See this [Listagg topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Comment: What if they only share A or B?

Comment: That is a good question OverMind, I am unsure how to deal with this. Currently I am thinking of using a *like* command in sql to pull those inner relationships out. Very confusing!