# Advanced Grouping in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as mentioned below:

```
-------------------------------  
EmpID  | Name     | Salary  
-------------------------------  
1      | AAA      | 10000
2      | BBB      | 10000
3      | CCC      | 15000
4      | DDD      | 15000
5      | EEE      | 20000
--------------------------------
```

I want to write a SQL query to group the table values as mentioned below:

```
---------------------  
Salary  |  Name  
---------------------  
10000   |  AAA  
        |  BBB
15000   |  CCC  
        |  DDD
20000   |  EEE
---------------------
```

Help me to achieve the output using sql query in sql server.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: SQL is not a presentation layer. This is typically a presentation problem.

Comment: What is wrong with a row for 10000 | AAA and another 10000 | BBB? SQL is not meant to make pretty data, just usable data.

Comment: Try [Sql Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx). It is part of Sql Server and can format your output how you want.

Comment: Other comments are rights but try my answer script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request normally must be run under Excel or other similary software but...

I emulate `GROUP BY` behaviour so you'll get only row with the wage valued and the other with the same wage with a NULL value:

```
create table salary(empid int, name varchar(10), wage int);

insert into salary values
(1, 'AAA', 10000),
(2, 'BBB', 10000),
(3, 'CCC', 15000),
(4, 'DDD', 15000),
(5, 'EEE', 20000);

SELECT s1.name, 
CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT 'X'
       FROM salary s3
       WHERE s3.empid < s1.empid
       AND s3.wage = s1.wage
    )
    THEN
       (SELECT wage FROM salary s2
       WHERE s2.name = s1.name)
    ELSE NULL
END
FROM salary s1
ORDER BY wage
```

`SELECT` get all employees, and for the first employee ID about wage group it shows the wage else shows NULL.

It is not properly you want but it's really similitude

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36f13/3/0)

Comment: I like your "don't do that, but if that's what you really want..." edit. That makes the answer really more interesting. +1

Comment: Thanks @Joe Taras.. Eventhough it is not giving the same output that I expected, I could make it up with few limitations as you mentioned (with NULL value)..

Comment: @Venkatesh: Because you are newbie, if this answer has accomplished to your task, please accept as good answer (clicking on tick). Have a nice day

Comment: @Venkatesh - if your report will not be further utilized, then you can cast wage values to varchar (`cast(wage as varchar)`) and change `ELSE NULL` to `ELSE ''` to get desired blank values in `Salary` column,

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what do you want, but you can list all names in one column like this:

```
Salary  |  Name  
---------------------  
10000   |  AAA, BBB
15000   |  CCC, DDD
20000   |  EEE
```

The following query, which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348687/2495654), should give above result:

```
SELECT Salary, STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + Name FROM Employees a
WHERE b.Salary = a.Salary FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') Name
FROM Employees b
GROUP BY Salary;
```

Comment: Thanks @yamny.. We could achieve as you mentioned.. But I would like to have name in separate rows with salary not repeating in the rows as I mentioned..