# Concatenate many rows into comma-separated list based on unique id

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation, string-aggregation

I'm new to SQL (running SQL Server 2012), the query I'm running is returning these results.

```
IDNum   Email
----------------
 1      a@a.com
 1      b@b.com
 1      c@c.com
 2      d@d.com
 2      e@e.com
 3      f@f.com
 3      g@g.com
 3      h@h.com
 4      i@i.com
 5      j@j.com
 5      k@k.com
```

I would like to get the following result set (a comma separated list unique to each id)

```
IDNum   Emails
---------------------------------
 1      a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com
 2      d@d.com,e@e.com
 3      f@f.com,g@g.com,h@h.com
 4      i@i.com
 5      j@j.com,k@k.com
```

I've been trying to follow some of the answers from other questions but not having any luck. I'm sure it's some combination of my inexperience & all the other questions I'm finding with this are just results from a single table. My query is getting results from multiple tables if that makes a difference, would be similar to

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    s.idnum, e.email
FROM
    student s
JOIN 
    email e ON e.guid = s.guid
WHERE 
    s.activeYear = 1 AND e.activeEmail = 1
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

******UPDATE******

I ended up using the following query after reading a few more articles here and on another website. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
USE databaseName

SELECT s.idnum,
STUFF(( SELECT ',' + e.email AS [text()]
        FROM email e
        WHERE
        e.guid = s.guid AND e.activeEmail = 1
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '' )
        AS emails
    FROM student s

WHERE s.activeYear = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you would do this with a LISTAGG function, but for SQL-Server try this question, there's a few different options there:

[ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)