# SQL two records, should be one

Tags: sql, join

I have been looking through for answers for this question, and am still struggling.

```
Location    Cashier TXN Date    Product Date    Time    Ref
Toronto     Z       15-01-04    15-01-04        090501  Transaction was a very
Toronto     Z       15-01-04    15-01-04        090501  intresting one
NewYork     X       15-01-04    15-01-04        123035  Transaction completed
London      Z       15-02-04    15-01-04        100612  This transaction had complications
London      Z       15-02-04    15-01-04        100612  in it. We need to follow up
Rochest     Y       15-01-04    15-01-04        153045  This transaction was a fun one to
Rochest     Y       15-01-04    15-01-04        153045  process
Vanc        L       15-01-04    15-01-04        174535  Something intresting
```

I would like the records with the same Location, Cashier, Dates, and Time to only appear once, with the two applicable reference lines being in one box... e.g.

```
Toronto     Z       15-01-04    15-01-04        090501  Transaction was a very intresting one
```

I know this is fairly basic, but any help would be appreciated, on my SQL learning journey

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And how do you know in which order the rows with the same location/cashier/dates should be concatenated? Rows in a relational table don't have an order. Based on the sample data you have shown us it's impossible to detect which is the first and which is the second row

Comment: What database is the data stored in?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: sounds like you need a group concat, given that you want all the Ref combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d498/1)

You can combine using STUFF and Group BY. Assuming you are using SQL Server.

```
Select location,Cashier,[Time],
  stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(ref as varchar(500))
           FROM t t2
           where t2.location = t1.location
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
Grom t t1
Group By location, Cashier,[Time]
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked perfectly! Loved the "Sample SQL Fiddle" option!

Just one additional followups, what would happen if I had up to 5 separate comments records? Would I just need to have additional t values?

Answer (score 0):

well if you are using oracle you can use listagg

```
SELECT location, cashier, txn_date, product_date, time       LISTAGG(ref, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ref) as "ref_list"
  FROM mytable;
```

Comment: this link shows how to do it using mysql, sqlserver and oracle   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Answer (score -1):

**If you data is as listed by you in sample use this query :**

This query ws done for MySQL.

```
  select distinct Location,
                  Cashier,
                  time,
                  concat((select ref
                           from test
                          where Location = 'Toronto' limit 1),
                         (select ref
                            from test
                           where Location = 'Toronto' limit 1 offset 1))
    from test;
```

**The output should be something like this:**

```
Toronto  | Z       |  90501 | Transaction was a veryintresting one
```

**For three values**

```
select distinct t.Location,
                  t.Cashier,
                  t.time,
                  concat((select ref
                           from test
                          where Location = 'Toronto' limit 1),
                         (select ref
                            from test
                           where Location = 'Toronto' limit 1 offset 1),
                           (select ref
                            from test
                           where Location = 'Toronto' limit 1 offset 2))
   from test t where t.Location = 'Toronto';
```

Comment: What happens is there are three records that need to be combined?

Comment: you just add a new concat with and offset of 2

Comment: This would work for this specific instance, but with so much hard coded into the query, it is not very dynamic.

Comment: ohh yeah , not at all ! but is start for him - i don't think stack should be the place to get your full solution.