# SQL Query to Work out Every Product Combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

I require a SQL query to work out every product combination.

I have three product categories (game, accessory, upgrade) and products assigned to each of these three categories:

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | category   | product   | prod_code  |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | game       | GTA       |        100 |
|  2 | game       | GTA1      |        200 |
|  3 | game       | GTA2      |        300 |
|  4 | accessory  | Play Pad  |        400 |
|  5 | accessory  | Xbox Pad  |        500 |
|  6 | upgrade    | Memory    |        600 |
|  6 | upgrade    | drive     |        700 |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to take one product from each of the categories and work out every single combination:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | combinations |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | 100,400,600  |
|  2 | 100,500,600  |
|  3 | 100,400,700  |
|  4 | 100,500,700  |
|  ? | etc          |
+----+--------------+
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance, Stuart

Comment: Use [For XML path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)  this will combine multiple rows into 1 for a given group (category) in you case

Comment: Not sure I understand.

Comment: ah I miss read the question.  I thought you were rolling up category when you're selecting 1 from each category. for all combinations.

Comment: The first thing to say is that you should not store one-to-many relations in the database using comma-separated strings. This is not what a database is for. After hitting the designer over the head with something hard, you should (if possible) expand the combinations column so that there is a separate row for each id-combination pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.[prod_code], ',', 
              t2.[prod_code], ',', 
              t3.[prod_code])
FROM (
   SELECT [prod_code]
   FROM mytable
   WHERE category = 'game') AS t1
CROSS JOIN (   
   SELECT [prod_code]
   FROM mytable
   WHERE category = 'accessory') AS t2
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT [prod_code]
   FROM mytable
   WHERE category = 'upgrade') AS t3
ORDER BY t1.[prod_code], t2.[prod_code], t3.[prod_code]
```

`CROSS JOIN` of derived tables, one for each category, produces the following cartesian product: `'game' products` x `'accessory' products` x `'upgrade' products`

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d973/3)

Comment: This would not be feasible for a large or indeterminate number of categories.

Comment: @jjt Yes I know, but the OP is *explicitly* talking about *three* products categories.

Comment: Do you have an alternative method? The server I am running the code on will not permit the usage 'concat is not a recognized built-in function name'

Comment: @Stuart Use `+`: `CAST(t1.[prod_code] AS VARCHAR(8)) + ',' + 
       CAST(t2.[prod_code] AS VARCHAR(8)) + ',' + 
       CAST(t3.[prod_code] AS VARCHAR(8))`

Comment: Damn, thats a lot of options! Thanks for your help.