# Summary report with help of SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a Summary report with the help of following table

table 1: `Account`

```
+----+------+---------------+
| Emp| T Amt|    Bill Id    |
+----+------+---------------+
|  12| 100  | 101           |
|  11| 200  | 102           |
|  12| 50   | 103           |
+----+------+---------------+
```

**Expected Output:-**

```
+----+------+---------------+
| Emp| T Amt|    Bill Id    |
+----+------+---------------+
|  12| 150  | 101,103       |
|  11| 200  | 102           |
+----+------+---------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
      Emp,
      sum([T Amt]),
      stuff((select ','+ [Bill Id] from Account a where a.Emp = b.Emp for xml path('')),1,1, '')  bill_ids
from Account b
group by Emp,bill_ids
order by Emp desc;
```