# How can I return 2 rows of a field within the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Each row in the query below returns 1 unique row. ***However***, if I were to add 2 more fields, the `job` and `suffix` field, I would get some rows with duplicate `item` numbers (this is expected).

I want to actually return the `job` and `suffix` row information, but all in one field and in one row separated by commas. [See this link for a description of what I want to do](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/). I can't use this example though because I don't have the ability to write to a table, I can only make queries/reports/subreports with this. How can I do this?

```
SELECT c.item, 
       c.qty_ordered                                 AS qty_expected, 
       Sum(j.qty_released)                           AS sum_qty_released, 
       Sum(j.qty_complete)                           AS sum_qty_complete, 
       ( Sum(j.qty_complete) - c.qty_ordered )       AS expected_variance, 
       ( Sum(j.qty_complete) - Sum(j.qty_released) ) AS regular_variance, 
       j.whse 
FROM   coitem AS c 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j 
                    ON c.item = j.item 
                       AND Dateadd(d, -6, c.due_date) = j.job_date 
WHERE  j.job_date = @jobdate 
       AND j.item IN (SELECT j.item AS current_item 
                      FROM   job AS j 
                      WHERE  j.job_date = @jobdate 
                             AND j.item NOT LIKE 'Indirect' 
                             AND j.job NOT LIKE 'C%') 
GROUP  BY c.item, 
          c.qty_ordered, 
          j.whse 
ORDER  BY j.whse, 
          c.item
```

**Update:**

I attempted to use `FOR XML Path` to solve this, but I can't get it to work. I get this error:

> `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.`

The trickiest part of this is that the information I want returned in one row is the job ***and*** the suffix. So I need to concatenate these 2 fields first then aggregate the rows into one field. But I figured since the aggregation is more difficult, I should start with that. Hence, my attempt below only focuses on the aggregation part.

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @jobdate datetime = '5/30/2016'

SELECT


    c.item,
    c.qty_ordered AS qty_expected,

    j1.job,
    j1.suffix,
    Sum(j1.qty_released) AS sum_qty_released,
    Sum(j1.qty_complete) AS sum_qty_complete,
    (Sum(j1.qty_complete)-c.qty_ordered) AS expected_variance,

    (Sum(j1.qty_complete)-Sum(j1.qty_released)) AS regular_variance,
    j1.whse
    STUFF(
        SELECT DISTINCT '' + j2.job
        FROM job AS j2 
        WHERE j1.job = j2.job AND j1.suffix = j2.suffix 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,0,'') data 

FROM

    coitem AS c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j1 ON c.item = j1.item AND DATEADD(d, -6, c.due_date) = j1.job_date

WHERE


    j1.job_date = @jobdate AND
    j1.item IN

        (SELECT

            j.item AS current_item

        FROM

            job AS j

        WHERE

            j.job_date = @jobdate AND
            j.item NOT LIKE 'Indirect' AND
            j.job NOT LIKE 'C%'
        )

GROUP BY

    c.item,
    c.qty_ordered,
    j1.whse,
    j1.job,
    j1.suffix

ORDER BY

    j1.whse,
    c.item
```

Comment: Will `CONCAT()` not work?

Comment: @scsimon what would I be concatenating? The 2 values I want to put together are on different rows. I could concatenate the `job` and `suffix`, that's easy. But the real goal is to get multiple row values into one row.

Comment: Sorry missed that part. Can you use `#temp` tables?

Comment: Not sure what those are. Maybe it's important to note that I'm not using SSMS. I am a lowly SSRS/Report Builder 3.0 peon right now :/

Comment: **Note:** `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in your query will work as `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use ListAgg().
In this post they explain you how to do it in MSSQL.
[ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)