# Concatenate, how to get different values from a column into one row?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to list a course number and then in one row, show the grades that course covers. I tried a concatenate, but it puts it on different rows.  I want to see:

```
6740    , , , 10, 11, 12.
```

But I'm getting this:

```
courseID    Grades
6740    , , , , , 12
6740    , , , , 11, 
6740    , , , 10, ,
```

This is the code I'm using (the grades are strings, not numbers):

```
select distinct c.courseID
,case when st.grade = '7' then '7' else '' end 
+ ', '
+ case when st.grade = '8' then '8' else ''end 
+ ', '
+ case when st.grade = '9' then '9' else ''end
+ ', '
+ case when st.grade = '10' then '10' else ''end
+ ', '
+ case when st.grade = '11' then '11' else ''end
+ ', '
+ case when st.grade = '12' then '12' else '' end
as Grades
from course c
inner join calendar cal on cal.calendarID = c.calendarID

inner join Section s on s.courseID = c.courseID
inner join Trial tr on tr.trialID = s.trialID and tr.calendarID =        cal.calendarID
    and tr.active = 1
inner join Roster r on r.sectionID = s.sectionID
inner join student st on st.personID = r.personID and st.calendarID = cal.calendarID
inner join sectionPlacement sp on sp.sectionID = s.sectionID
where c.calendarID in (1058, 1054)
    and c.active = 1
```

Can someone help steer me in the right direction to get one row per course showing all the grades?  I'm using Microsoft SQL 2012

Comment: please show current result and expected result.Your sample data is not helpfull atleast to me

Comment: Seeing as you want it _per course_, a solution may be to `GROUP BY courseID` and use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will concatenate your grades per course. You can specify the _separator_ (comma in your case) using it too. Sample data would help answers be more specific.

Comment: Kinda sounds like you're after a `pivot` or perhaps `list_Agg()` but I don't think SQL Server supports lIst_Agg...  though it can be simulated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: I tried to show it above, but I can't seem to paste an excel grid? It's very simple. I want the courseID column to show 6740, then the Grades column to show 10,11,12 (meaning the course is taught in three grades).  But instead it gives me three separate rows, showing courseID 6740 on three consecutive rows, one with grade 10, one with grade 11, and one with grade 12. I'm sorry I'm not sure how to make it clearer without showing the excel result grid.

Comment: Yes, I saw something on the list_Agg and string_Agg in some research I did before posting this question, but you are correct, the sql I'm using does not support those functions. That is what I'm looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Jonathon - unfortunately the GROUP_CONCAT is not a recognized built-in function name either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

Short explanation: This approach simulates the *MySQL-Group-Concat*. If you need your grades in dedicated columns you need `PIVOT` or `GROUP BY with MAX(CASE...)`, or dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @course TABLE(ID INT,CoursName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @course VALUES(6740,'Course 6740'),(9999,'Course 9999');

DECLARE @grade TABLE(ID INT,GradeName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @grade VALUES(7,'Grade 7'),(8,'Grade 8'),(9,'Grade 9');


DECLARE @data TABLE(CourseID INT, GradeID INT);
INSERT INTO @data 
VALUES
 (6740,7),(6740,8),(6740,9)
,(9999,7),(9999,9);

SELECT d.CourseID
      ,c.CoursName
      ,STUFF(
          (
            SELECT ', ' + g.GradeName
            FROM @data AS d1
            INNER JOIN @grade AS g ON d1.GradeID=g.ID
            WHERE d1.CourseID=d.CourseID
            FOR XML PATH('')
          ),1,2,'') AS Grades

FROM @data AS d
INNER JOIN @course AS c ON d.CourseID=c.ID
GROUP BY  d.CourseID,c.CoursName
```

This is the result

```
CourseID    CoursName     Grades
6740        Course 6740   Grade 7, Grade 8, Grade 9
9999        Course 9999   Grade 7, Grade 9
```

Comment: Thank you Shnugo. I've been looking through this, and while I understand the concept that I need a pivot or to emulate the group_concat - I'm not understanding this code. I don't know what STUFF is doing. I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi @Karen, just try this `SELECT(SELECT TOP 5 ', ' + name FROM sys.objects FOR XML PATH(''))`. You will get a concatenated list of the first 5 names in `sys.objects`. They are separated with a comma and a blank and - what is disturbing - the string starts with a comma and a blank. The function `STUFF` does nothing more than to jump to index 1, take away two characters and *stuff* in the third parameter, which is an empty string. You could reach quite the same with `SUBSTRING`... No miracle or magic :-)

Comment: Thank you for that explanation Shnugo!!! I didn't get a chance to get back to it today, but hope to tomorrow.