# Need help grouping multiple rows into single string based on GROUP BY?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, group-by

This question may have been asked before but I've been doing some digging and can't find anything quite like it. Thanks in advance

EDIT: Totally forgot. We're using SQL 2005 (otherwise I'd likely just use GROUP_CONCAT)

Sample Table:

```
ID  CATEGORY    ATTRIBUTE
1   A   Piano
1   A   Saxophone
1   B   Jazz
1   C   Mellow
1   C   Pensive
2   A   Drums
2   A   Guitar
2   B   Rock
2   B   Classics
2   C   Upbeat
2   C   High Energy
```

Desired Output:

```
ID  CATEGORY    ATTRIBUTE
1   A   Piano, Saxophone
1   B   Jazz
1   C   Mellow, Pensive
2   A   Drums, Guitar
2   B   Rock, Classics
2   C   Upbeat, High Energy
```

Comment: Try the search term 'pivot'

Comment: Can you show the code you have attempted?

Comment: Google:  "<your database name here> aggregate string concatenation".

Comment: One very similiar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39207098/5089204

Comment: Btw: Why is this tagged with `xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a standard old style nested query using `XML PATH` should work just fine for SQL 2005.

```
DECLARE @TableName TABLE
(
     ID         INT
    ,CATEGORY   NVARCHAR(5)
    ,ATTRIBUTE  NVARCHAR(50)
    ,PRIMARY KEY(ID, CATEGORY, ATTRIBUTE)
)

INSERT INTO @TableName
(
     ID         
    ,CATEGORY
    ,ATTRIBUTE
)
VALUES
    (1   ,'A'   ,'Piano'            ),
    (1   ,'A'   ,'Saxophone'        ),
    (1   ,'B'   ,'Jazz'             ),
    (1   ,'C'   ,'Mellow'           ),
    (1   ,'C'   ,'Pensive'          ),
    (2   ,'A'   ,'Drums'            ),
    (2   ,'A'   ,'Guitar'           ),
    (2   ,'B'   ,'Rock'             ),
    (2   ,'B'   ,'Classics'         ),
    (2   ,'C'   ,'Upbeat'           ),
    (2   ,'C'   ,'High Energy'      );


WITH CTE_Concatenate 
AS
(
    SELECT  ID
            ,CATEGORY
            ,(
                SELECT ATTRIBUTE + ','
                FROM @TableName [Inner]
                WHERE [Outer].ID = [Inner].ID AND [Outer].CATEGORY = [Inner].CATEGORY
                FOR XML PATH('')
             ) AS ATTRIBUTES
    FROM    @TableName [Outer]
    GROUP BY    ID, CATEGORY
)
SELECT  ID
        ,CATEGORY
        ,LEFT(ATTRIBUTES, LEN(ATTRIBUTES) - 1) AS ATTRIBUTES
FROM    CTE_Concatenate;
```

The query can be simplified further using the `STUFF` function as follow:

```
SELECT  ID
        ,CATEGORY
        ,STUFF( (
            SELECT ',' + ATTRIBUTE 
            FROM @TableName [Inner]
            WHERE [Outer].ID = [Inner].ID AND [Outer].CATEGORY = [Inner].CATEGORY
            FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') AS ATTRIBUTES
FROM    @TableName [Outer]
GROUP BY    ID, CATEGORY;
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Unfortunately I received an update that'll require more work but I'll post another question for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT ID,CATEGORY,GROUP_CONCAT(ATTRIBUTE)
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY ID,CATEGORY
```

Comment: +1 for MySQL or SQLite, but other brands of RDBMS use other syntax. OP was not specific about which brand he uses.

Comment: You're right my bad. Just edited the original post, we're using SQL 2005

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS ONE

```
SELECT ID,
        CATEGORY,
        ATTRIBUTE1
 FROM TABLENAME TB
 cross apply 
   (SELECT TB1.ATTRIBUTE + ', '
    FROM TABLENAME TB1
    WHERE TB1.ID = TB.ID  For XML PATH(''))A1 (ATTRIBUTE1)
GROUP BY TB.ID,TB.CATEGORY
```

Comment: Didn't quite do it. The attributes are now simply repeating on the Attribute1 column but separated by commas.

i.e "Rock, Rock, Rock, Rock, Rock, Rock, Rock, Rock"

Comment: Did you make a change to the original query? They seem the same

Answer (score 0):

FOR MS SQL    Use this syntax

```
SELECT table_name, LEFT(column_names , LEN(column_names )-1) AS column_names
FROM information_schema.columns AS extern
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT column_name + ','
    FROM information_schema.columns AS intern
    WHERE extern.table_name = intern.table_name
    FOR XML PATH('')
) pre_trimmed (column_names)
GROUP BY table_name, column_names;
```