# How to see the actual values while grouping by instead of count in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
Id   Name
------------
1    Jack
2    John
3    Maria
4    Jack
5    Jack
6    John
```

I am trying to see all the Ids having the same name in one column.

```
select Count(Id), Name
from myTable
group by Name
```

The query above is giving me the number of Ids having the same name. But what I would like to see is:

```
    Id    Name
    ------------
    1,4,5 Jack
    2,6   John
    3     Maria
```

How can I provide this? Thanks

Comment: That's a SQL anti pattern; one field should not contain multiple values.  If you explain why you need this, how it will be used, we may be able to provide an alternative pattern / solution.

Comment: @xQbert `ListAgg()` is only in Oracle.

Comment: The MSFT equivelant to `ListAgg()` is the function you're looking for: use `for XML path` &  `stuff` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: @MatBailie The field does not have multiple values.

Comment: @paparazzi - A single string with `'1,4,5'` is a non atomic value.  Why the necro comment?

Comment: @MatBailie  Not going to play semantics with you.   String is a report is not a SQL field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, Name varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Jack'),
(2,'John'),
(3,'Maria'),
(4,'Jack'),
(5,'Jack'),
(6,'John')

Select Name
      ,IDs  = Stuff((Select Distinct ','+cast(ID as varchar(25))
                     From   @YourTable
                     Where  Name=A.Name
                     For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From  (Select Distinct Name From @YourTable ) A
```

Returns

```
Name    IDs
Jack    1,4,5
John    2,6
Maria   3
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You still nailed it.  I just happened to be working on  a string array for my treasury rates

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  Thanks.  I must confess, I was a little disappointed ... No balloons