# How to have output result select in a list with sql server as listagg in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field with multi value with diffent IDs For example :

```
ID | Email|
+--+------+
|1 |a@mail|
|2 |b@mail|
|3 |c@mail|
```

I would like to have this output

```
|Email             |
-------------------+
|a@mail;b@mail;c@mail|
```

I tried with STUFF and XML PATH based on this post [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver/19052439#19052439) but I does not work.

Any help will be appreciated

Best Regards

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in SQL Server:

```
select stuff( (select ';' + email
               from t
               for xml path (''), type
              ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'
                     ), 1, 1, ''
            )
```