# SQL - Consolidate results of multiple queries in 1 variable or column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to consolidate results of multiple queries in 1 column or variable.
I have this Query :-

```
select Id from EmployeeDetail where Code = 'ABC1'
select Id from EmployeeDetail where Code = 'ABC2'

... So  On till ABC200
```

I want all the Ids in a 1 variable to use it further.

I am trying to use foreach to get this. How to get this in a 1 variable to use it in further different query.

I have tried for example the below to get a string in 1 Concatenating variable :- Below code was just a trial, it is not woking on actual query.

```
declare @num int
declare @num1 VARCHAR(MAX)

set @num = 1

declare @results table ( val int )

while (@num < 84)
begin
  insert into @results ( val ) values ( @num )
  set @num = @num + 1
  set @num1 += '5000'
  select @num1
end
```

Comment: Do you want Id value as 1,2,3 like that..?

Comment: If you want all the rows to be in a single string, see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver). But you intend to use it in another query... then is the combined form really useful for you? You may instead want to iterate over the first resultset.

Comment: add what is your last expected output ? you want result or assing to varibale  in commo seprate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the EmployeeDetail codes your are fetching all match some pattern, then you can achieve what you want using the simple query below:

```
declare @AllIDs varchar(max)
set @AllIDs = ''

select 
    @AllIDs = (@AllIDs + cast(ID as varchar(10)) + ',') 
from EmployeeDetail WHERE Code like 'ABC%'
```

After you run it, variable @AllIDs will contain all the IDs separated with ',' .

Comment: @Anup it's because you are using SQL 2005 or SQL 2008 compatibility in DB. See the updated answer. I ran the original version successfully against SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Mine is SQL Server MS 2014

Comment: yes but your DB compatibility Options may have been set to 2005 or 2008 only. Right click the DB, then Properties, then Options. There u will see the Compatibility Level. Did you run the updated code snippet?

Comment: It is still showing the same error with updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129507/discussion-between-andrews-and-anup).

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding you want to concatenate the result of all IDs with code as ABC1, ABC2, .. ABC200. Check my below solution and hope it helps you.

```
declare @num int
declare @text VARCHAR(MAX)

set @text = 'ABC'
set @num = 1

declare @results table ( val varchar(10) )

while (@num <= 200)
begin
  insert into @results ( val ) values (@text + cast(@num as varchar(3)) )
  set @num = @num + 1
end

Select ID from EmployeeDetail where Code in (Select val from @results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question can distributed in two part

1. Generate variable value .
2. Filter result on data generated on step1.

   ```
   --Step 1

   declare @num int
   declare @text VARCHAR(MAX)

   set @text = 'ABC'
   set @num = 1

   declare @results table ( val varchar(10) )

   while (@num <= 200)
   begin
     insert into @results ( val ) values (@text + cast(@num as varchar(3)) )
     set @num = @num + 1
   end

   --Step 2

   Select ID from EmployeeDetails e
   inner join @results r on r.val=e.Code
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Prepare the data
DECLARE @EmployeeDetail TABLE (Id int identity(1,1), Code varchar(10))
INSERT @EmployeeDetail VALUES ('ABC1'), ('ABC2'), ('DEF'), ('ABC3')

DECLARE 
    @CodePattern varchar(10) = 'ABC',
    @RangeFrom int = 1,
    @RangeTo int = 200

DECLARE @Ids varchar(max) = (SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + CAST(Id AS varchar(10)) 
    FROM @EmployeeDetail 
    WHERE 
        -- The pattern of the code is prefix + number
        -- Can use LIKE and BETWEEN to replace your multiple query
        code LIKE @CodePattern + '%' 
        AND SUBSTRING(code, LEN(@CodePattern) + 1, 10) BETWEEN @RangeFrom AND @RangeTo
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, ''))

PRINT @Ids
```