# What Function Support to do triple des Encryption /Decryption in sql server 2000?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

Here I Use EncrytByPassPharse() which does not support in Sql server 2000..
So,What function I should Use for Encrytion/Decrytion using 3DES?

```
INSERT INTO  login_details(username,password) VALUES('smith2',EncryptByPassPhrase('12','XXXX'))
```

Comment: What is the query behind this view?

Comment: Q: You have to insert a CR/LF (enter) within text (columna `ScheduleInfo`) or you have to split first line in two *separate* line ?

Comment: I have to split first line in two separate line

Comment: Your query uses SQL Server [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15477847/2055998) of `GROUP_CONCAT` type of functionality.  If you do not need it, change it.

Comment: I think you are confusing the concept of SQL View (which is a commodity to write simpler queries) with a problem of displaying the result data in a required way....

Comment: If you have a new question, you should *ask a new question*, not edit an existing question to completely change its meaning.