# How to get value of ID's separated by comma

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
tbl A           tbl B
ID | Value      ID |  tblA_ID  | Qty
1  | CGK        1  |  2,3      | 100
2  | BNK        2  |  2        | 85
3  | DPK        3  |  1,3,4    | 200
4  | CMG        4  |  1,2      | 120
```

I want this output when I join them:

```
 tblBID|  tblA_Values  | Qty
 1     |  BNK,DPK      | 100
 2     |  BNK          | 85
 3     |  CGK,DPK,CMG  | 200
 4     |  CGK,BNK      | 120
```

I don't know the keyword to search for questions and answers, that is why I am posting this question.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Based on your screen name I would guess that this is homework.

Comment: You should normalize your tables instead.

Comment: you got me, i'm really new to sql programming. a simple join is ok, but this kind is new to me

Comment: @felix normalize isn't necessary, this is just a dummy table

Comment: @Lmao What Felix means is that *if* you are allowed to change the structure of the tables, then you need to change B so that it is a child relation to A. In other words, B's tblA_ID column should be number and not a string, it should be a foreign key that references A.ID, and the resulting B table should have 8 rows. The only trouble with that approach is that it requires you to make a decision about the Qty column. For the rows in *your* B that have multiple tblA_Values in the string, how do you attribute the Qty amongst the multiple values? Do you choose an approximate average?

Comment: @jeff so the table should be like : tblB (1.2), (1.3), (2.2), (3.1), (3.3), (3.4), (4.1), (4.2) right?

Comment: @Lmao You're close to what I was thinking. If we were to express each row as a tuple, they would be this: (1, 2, 50), (1, 3, 50), (2, 2, 85), (3, 1, 66), (3, 3, 66), (3, 4, 67), (4, 1, 60), (4, 2, 60). Then your query will be *much* simpler. If you *must* produce the output table such that you join A.Value together with ',' you'll have to use the [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver) of Oracle's LISTAGG function. It's not as easy as Oracle is but it will still be less code than trying to use your original schema.

Comment: @jeff I totally agree to that. I may be new to sql, but your statement is on point and make sense. Now i have no idea why my lecturer gave me this kind of homework, at first i thought this is an easy work, until i came to stackoverflow and realize that this is a critical error in database design. Thank you, i will notify my lecturer about this.

Comment: @Lmao Modeling the world is fun and especially when you implement the world and see how things go. I hope you and your prof enjoy the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than a simple join.  There are actually 3 major parts to be concerned with.

1) Parse or Split your data

2) Join the parsed results with tblA

3) Reconstruct the the string via the XML/Stuff()

If you can't use the UDF, this can easily be modified to an in-line process.

**The SQL [or dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e79db36e1429eea79e11faf0cc4d4a61)**

```
Select tblBID      = A.ID
      ,tblA_Values = B.S
      ,A.Qty
 From TblB A
 Cross Apply (
               Select S=Stuff((Select ',' +Value 
                                From  (
                                      Select B1.RetSeq,Value            
                                       From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.[tblA_ID],',') B1
                                       Join TblA B2 on B1.RetVal = B2.ID
                                      ) X1
                                Order By RetSeq
                                For XML Path (''))
                              ,1,1,'')
             )B
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

> **EDIT - In-Line Option (No UDF)**

```
Select tblBID      = A.ID
      ,tblA_Values = B.S
      ,A.Qty
 From TblB A
 Cross Apply (
               Select S=Stuff((Select ',' +Value 
                                From  (
                                      Select B1.RetSeq,Value            
                                       From (
                                                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                                                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                                                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[tblA_ID],',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                                                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                                            ) B1
                                       Join TblA B2 on B1.RetVal = B2.ID
                                      ) X1
                                Order By RetSeq
                                For XML Path (''))
                              ,1,1,'')
             )B
```

Comment: This actually works, but for a beginner like me, posting a query like this, my Lecturer must be so suspicious, but anyway thanks.

Comment: @Lmao  Fair enough, and I appreciate your honesty.  That said, I can't help you regarding your instructor.  :)