# SELECT STUFF and where clause to narrow down the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT Stuff(
  (SELECT N', ' +  activity FROM contact_categories FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')
```

This displays all the information from the activity column in one string. What I'd like to do is return it as one string but for each primary key.

So in the table it would look like this

```
Contact  Activity
1        Green
1        Red
1        Blue
2        Green
2        Red
2        Blue
3        Green
3        Red
3        Blue
```

Instead of displaying it as Green, Green, Green, Red, Red, Red, Blue, Blue, Blue all in one string. I would like it to show:

```
1  Green, Red, Blue

2  Green, Red, Blue

3  Green, Red, Blue
```

I tried adding a from and where clause:

```
SELECT Stuff(
  (SELECT N', ' +  activity FROM contact_categories FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') 
FROM contact_categories
WHERE contact_number = #
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Product specific query.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    contact,
    Stuff(
  (SELECT N', ' +  activity FROM contact_categories WHERE Contact = S.Contact FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') 
FROM contact_categories AS S
GROUP BY contact
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct contact, Stuff(
  (SELECT  N', ' +  activity FROM contact_categories t2 WHERE t1.contact = t2.contact FOR 
   XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') 
FROM contact_categories  t1
```

Comment: It's also Given Same Result

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using LISTAGG?

---

```
SELECT contact,
    listagg(activity, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY 1) AS activity
FROM contact_categories
GROUP BY contact;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030