# How to coalesce into multiple columns with grouping?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

If you run the below code you will get a result that looks like the following:

```
ITEM    DIFF_QTY        DATE_OUTGO                              WAREH  COMPANY
1000    -5, -3, -4,     2017-08-01, 2017-08-02, 2017-08-03,     WH     CMP
```

Which is great, this is the output that I am looking for. Sadly this only works when a specific **ITEM** is selected. If I remove the **WHERE** then everything is put on the same row of output.

So how would I separate the results by grouping **(ITEM, WAREH, COMPANY)**? So that the end result would look like this:

```
ITEM    DIFF_QTY        DATE_OUTGO                              WAREH  COMPANY
1000    -5, -3, -4,     2017-08-01, 2017-08-02, 2017-08-03,     WH     CMP
1001    -10, -13        2017-08-01, 2017-08-03                  WH     CMP
```

### Code

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
    ITEM nvarchar(32),
    DIFF_QTY nvarchar(6), 
    DATE_OUTGO nvarchar(10),
    WAREH nvarchar(5),
    COMPANY nvarchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO @tempTable (ITEM, DIFF_QTY, DATE_OUTGO, WAREH, COMPANY)
VALUES 
(1000, '-5', '2017-08-01', 'WH', 'CMP'),
(1000, '-3', '2017-08-02', 'WH', 'CMP'),
(1000, '-4', '2017-08-03', 'WH', 'CMP'),
(1001, '-10', '2017-08-01', 'WH', 'CMP'),
(1001, '-13', '2017-08-03', 'WH', 'CMP')

SELECT * 
FROM @tempTable

DECLARE @itemNum nvarchar(32)
DECLARE @diffQty nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @dateOutgo nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @warehouse nvarchar(5)
DECLARE @company nvarchar(5)

SET @diffQty = ''
SET @dateOutgo = ''

SELECT 
    @itemNum = ITEM, 
    @diffQty = @diffQTY + DIFF_QTY + ', ',
    @dateOutgo = @dateOutgo + DATE_OUTGO + ', ', 
    @warehouse = WAREH, 
    @company = COMPANY 
FROM 
    @tempTable
WHERE 
    ITEM = 1000

SELECT @itemNum ITEM_NUM, @diffQty DIFF_QTY, @dateOutgo DATE_OUTGO, @warehouse WAREHOUSE, @company COMPANY
```

*I've looked at multiple threads about coalesce but pretty much every solution requires that you don't do multiple things at the same time (SELECT, GROUP, COALESCE, Multiple columns etc...)*

Comment: Search for STRING_AGG in SQL Server. There are plenty of ways XML/CLR function/STRING_AGG in SQL Server 2017. **[ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)** Also using `@var = @var + ...` could be undefined.

Comment: I'll look it up (eyed over it earlier), does it work with 2016?

Comment: Here you have solution using [SQL Server 2017 String_AGG](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=515381cf9f30021984a130d82a17f90c).

Comment: @lad2025 That looked really elegant!

Comment: @lad2025 Sadly I can't use it. 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: As I said it is available from SQL Server 2017(aka vNext) or  Azure SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use *scalar variables*, like `@itemNum nvarchar(32)`, to store *tabular* data.

The output you want to achieve is most commonly generated in SQL Server using `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT t.ITEM,
       STUFF((SELECT  ',' + x.DIFF_QTY
              FROM @tempTable AS x
              WHERE x.ITEM = t.ITEM AND 
                    x.WAREH = t.WAREH AND
                    x.COMPANY = t.COMPANY
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS DIFF_QTY,
       STUFF((SELECT  ',' + x.DATE_OUTGO
              FROM @tempTable AS x
              WHERE x.ITEM = t.ITEM AND 
                    x.WAREH = t.WAREH AND
                    x.COMPANY = t.COMPANY
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS DATE_OUTGO
FROM @tempTable AS t
GROUP BY t.ITEM, t.WAREH, t.COMPANY
```

Output:

```
ITEM    DIFF_QTY    DATE_OUTGO
-----------------------------------------------------
1000    -5,-3,-4    2017-08-01,2017-08-02,2017-08-03
1001    -10,-13     2017-08-01,2017-08-03
```

Comment: This is the fastest out of the answers (slightly faster than Felix).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FOR XML PATH('')` to concatenate the values:

```
SELECT
    t1.ITEM,
    a.DIFF_QTY,
    b.DATE_OUTGO,
    t1.WAREH,
    t1.COMPANY
FROM @tempTable t1
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT DIFF_QTY =  STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(t2.DIFF_QTY AS VARCHAR(100))
        FROM @tempTable t2
        WHERE
            t2.ITEM = t1.ITEM
            AND t2.WAREH = t1.WAREH
            AND t2.COMPANY = t2.COMPANY
        ORDER BY t2.DATE_OUTGO
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')  
) a
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT DATE_OUTGO = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(t2.DATE_OUTGO AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM @tempTable t2
        WHERE
            t2.ITEM = t1.ITEM
            AND t2.WAREH = t1.WAREH
            AND t2.COMPANY = t2.COMPANY
        ORDER BY t2.DATE_OUTGO
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')  
) b
GROUP BY
    t1.ITEM, t1.WAREH, t1.COMPANY, a.DIFF_QTY, b.DATE_OUTGO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
    ITEM nvarchar(32),
    DIFF_QTY nvarchar(6), 
    DATE_OUTGO nvarchar(10),
    WAREH nvarchar(5),
    COMPANY nvarchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO @tempTable (ITEM, DIFF_QTY, DATE_OUTGO, WAREH, COMPANY)
VALUES 
(1000, '-5', '2017-08-01', 'WH', 'CMP'),
(1000, '-3', '2017-08-02', 'WH', 'CMP'),
(1000, '-4', '2017-08-03', 'WH', 'CMP'),
(1001, '-10', '2017-08-01', 'WH', 'CMP'),
(1001, '-13', '2017-08-03', 'WH', 'CMP')

SELECT * 
FROM @tempTable

DECLARE @itemNum nvarchar(32)
DECLARE @diffQty nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @dateOutgo nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @warehouse nvarchar(5)
DECLARE @company nvarchar(5)

SET @diffQty = ''
SET @dateOutgo = ''



SELECT distinct  ITEM , 

              STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(DIFF_QTY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [text()]
         FROM  @tempTable temp
         where t.ITEM=temp.ITEM                                         
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')  DIFF_QTY, 

                      STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(DATE_OUTGO AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [text()]
         FROM  @tempTable temp      
          where t.ITEM=temp.ITEM                                   
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')  DATE_OUTGO,
        WAREH,COMPANY
        from @tempTable t
```

Hope it works exactly you want

Comment: It gives the correct output, but is very slow compared to the other solutions. Thanks anyway!