# SQL Table hierarchy side by side values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table

```
ManagerID   | EmpID
------------+-------
M01         | 100 
M01         | 101 
M02         | 102 
M02         | 103 
M02         | 104 
M03         | 105 
M04         | 106
```

I need it to look like the following:

```
ManagerID | EmpID
----------+------------
M01       | 100,101       
M02       | 102,103,104   
M03       | 105           
M04       | 106
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of question comes up all the time.  See the sample script below.

```
       SELECT CategoryId,
               MAX( CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
               MAX( CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
               MAX( CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
               MAX( CASE seq WHEN 4 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END )
          FROM ( SELECT p1.CategoryId, p1.ProductName,
                        ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                            FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p2
                            WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId
                            AND p2.ProductName <= p1.ProductName )
                 FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p1 ) D ( CategoryId, ProductName, seq )
         GROUP BY CategoryId ;

SELECT p1.CategoryId,
       ( SELECT ProductName + ',' 
           FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p2
          WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId
          ORDER BY ProductName
            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Products
      FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p1
      GROUP BY CategoryId ;


SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId, ProductNames
    FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p1
   CROSS APPLY ( SELECT ProductName + ',' 
                     FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p2
                     WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId 
                     ORDER BY ProductName 
                     FOR XML PATH('') )  D ( ProductNames )
```

[image]

[image]

It would be worth your time to see all the examples from the link below.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following t-sql:

```
Select distinct 
    T2.ManagerID, 
    substring((Select ',' + T1.EmpID  AS [text()]
               From dbo.table T1
               Where T1.ManagerID = T2.ManagerID
               Order By T1.ManagerID
               For Xml Path('')), 2, 1000) [EmployeeID]
From 
    dbo.table T2
```