# Joining and returning a table from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My model is

```
ID
Name
DOB
Favourite Foods
```

where favourite foods is a list. I currently have my own defined table type,

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FoodList] 
    AS TABLE 
       (
            [Food] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Food] DESC)
       )
```

My current select looks like this

```
SELECT TOP 20 p.Id, p.Name, p.DOB 
FROM dbo.People p
```

Two tables, `People` and `PeopleFood` - the latter is where I need to do the join from and it has a FK on the `People.Id`

I know I need to return `@FoodList` but I just have no idea how to populate it.

---

**Expected output**

```
¦ ID ¦ Name ¦ DOB ¦ Favourite Foods (returned as @FoodList) ¦
¦ 1  ¦ TIM  ¦ --  ¦ Pizza, Fries                            ¦
¦ 3  ¦ BOB  ¦ --  ¦ Fries, Burgers, Chilli                  ¦
```

**Tables**

People

```
¦ ID ¦ Name ¦ DOB ¦
¦ 1  ¦ TIM  ¦ --  ¦
¦ 2  ¦ JOE  ¦ --  ¦
¦ 3  ¦ BOB  ¦ --  ¦
```

Food

```
¦ PersonId ¦ Food    ¦
¦ 1        ¦ Pizza   ¦
¦ 1        ¦ Fries   ¦
¦ 3        ¦ Fries   ¦
¦ 3        ¦ Burgers ¦
¦ 3        ¦ Chilli  ¦
```

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas As I've already outlined. I can't figure out how to do the join. I've just been scouring StackOverflow for a similar thing, most seem to simply be returning the temp table directly with no other output.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @AnkitBajpa I have added some more information.

Comment: Try this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: Select Top without Order By D: