# SQL Server - LIST AGG with quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, listagg

I'm trying to use the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver) to concatenate a grouped collection of strings except I'd like the output to have quotes around each item.

```
Field A | Field B
1       |  A
1       |  B
2       |  A

1 | "A","B"
2 | "A"

SELECT FieldA , STUFF(( SELECT  ','+ FieldB FROM TableName a
WHERE b.FieldA = a.FieldA FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1, '')  Members
FROM TableName b
GROUP BY FieldA;
```

I've tried adding quotes before and after the comma but the format isn't correct.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `''''` /`'"'`to XML + STUFF method:

```
select distinct t1.FieldA,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + ''''+ t2.FieldB + ''''
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') data
from yourtable t1;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/EDX44422)**

**EDIT:**

Or use [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql):

```
select distinct t1.FieldA,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(t2.FieldB, '"')
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') data
from yourtable t1;
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/VIVQX28030)**

Answer (score 1):

I like first suggestion better, but here is a variation:

```
SELECT FIELDA, ISNULL([1],'') + ' ' + ISNULL([2], '')
FROM
    (SELECT   FIELDA, ISNULL(QUOTENAME(FieldB, '"'),'') AS FIELDB
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fielda ORDER BY fielda) AS tbl
    FROM yourtable)a
PIVOT (MAX(fieldb) FOR tbl IN ([1],[2])) AS pvt
```