# All ids into one row with concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

He

Anyone know how to get the same ids here into one row along with the other column after the comma, so group by id where there is another record from other column.

```
   SELECT 
   CONCAT(p.ID, ', ', '', s.[value]) 'id, OtherColumn'

  FROM [Test].[Person].[Name] s
  INNER JOIN [Test].[Person].[Nameref] sr ON s.Id = sr.ID
  INNER JOIN [Test2].[Test2] p ON sr.Id = p.ID
   GROUP BY p.ID, s.value

1, 4GL
1, Web
1, CCS
```

Needs to be:

```
1 , 4GL, Web, CCS
```

Thanks

Comment: This has been asked and answered literally thousands of times.

Comment: Simulate oracle `ListAgg()` using forXmlPath here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver or use `string_agg()` if you have 2017.

Comment: I think searching for "Building a comma separated list?" on this site should help, or maybe any one of the other 999 other posts that Sean mentions...

Comment: I don't want to show all the values for value just the ones that person nameref has assigned.