# SQL: Groupby and arrange different row values under one column to one horizontal row in second column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the logic I want to implement (easier to show in tables than describe in text):

[image]

Using python, I was able to achieve my desired table using the code below:

```
df_3 = df_2.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['reqmnt'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

How do I do this in SQL?

Comment: Which RDBMS will you be using. String Aggregation (generic name for what you are doing here) is implemented differently in each product (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Comment: I checked the ListAGG and tried the code there ... it does not work / I cannot get it to work

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for you:

```
DECLARE @T table
(
    a varchar(10)
    , b varchar(10)
    , c varchar(10)
    , reqmnt varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO @T (a, b, c, reqmnt)
VALUES
('AC1', 'BA2', 'test', 'C1')
, ('AC1', 'BA2', 'test', 'PAN')
, ('AC1', 'BA2', 'test', 'Woot')

SELECT DISTINCT
    a
    , b
    , c
    ,
        RTRIM(
            (
                SELECT reqmnt + ' '
                FROM @T t2
                WHERE
                    t2.a = t1.a
                    AND t2.b = t1.b
                    AND t2.c = t1.c
                ORDER BY reqmnt -- this line is optional
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            )
        ) reqmnt
FROM @T t1
```