# Unable to join multiple rows into single by using CAST or CASE in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table where it can have multiple records with same id and I want to make it single string. Here in stack overflow I found some examples which shows the use of either `CAST` or `CASE`.

I tried both of them but none of them seems to work. Meaning, query works but returns result in separate lines. I couldn't figure our what am I missing here?

**Query - 1:** Using `CAST`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.Name AS CallCenter,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) Name,
       d.DNIS,
       s.ScriptId,
      CAST(sL.Line + ';' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Script ,
       sL.ScriptLineId
FROM CallCenterScript s WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT JOIN CallCenterScriptLine sL WITH (NOLOCK) ON sL.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenterDNIS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenter c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = s.CallCenterId
WHERE (s.IsDeleted = 0 OR s.IsDeleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY DNIS ASC
```

**Query - 2:** Using `CASE`

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.Name AS CallCenter,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) Name,
       d.DNIS,
       s.ScriptId,
      CASE
          WHEN @Result IS NULL
          THEN sL.Line 
          ELSE @Result + ';' + sL.Line
       END as Script ,
       sL.ScriptLineId
FROM CallCenterScript s WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT JOIN CallCenterScriptLine sL WITH (NOLOCK) ON sL.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenterDNIS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenter c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = s.CallCenterId
WHERE (s.IsDeleted = 0 OR s.IsDeleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY DNIS ASC
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Sample:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Comment: "none of them seems to work" doesn't help at all.  What does not work mean???  No result???  Error out??? null??  wrong result???

Comment: Have you tried `CONCAT()`?  `CONCAT(@Result, sL.Line)`

Comment: @Eric Sorry for confusion. I have updated my question. Hope it helps. I also tried `CONCAT` but it returns same result.

Comment: I don't know what you want.  Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Eric Updated my question.

Comment: Look up `FOR XML PATH`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Eric Thanks for suggestion. I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I used `FOR XML PATH` and achieved what I wanted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.Name AS CallCenter,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) Name,
       d.DNIS,
       s.ScriptId,
       (
          SELECT Line + '; '
          FROM CallCenterScriptLine
          WHERE ScriptId = s.ScriptId
          ORDER BY ScriptLineId
          FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS Script
FROM CallCenterScript s WITH (NOLOCK) 
     LEFT JOIN CallCenterScriptLine sL WITH (NOLOCK) ON sL.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenterDNIS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenter c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = s.CallCenterId
WHERE(s.IsDeleted = 0
      OR s.IsDeleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY DNIS ASC
```