# Issues when converting ListAGG to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, string-aggregation

Oracle query that I am converting to SQL Server

```
select
    (select LISTAGG(mycase, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_gross_amount)
    from
         (select * 
           from (   select th.CONTACT_ID,
                         th.created_dt,
                         sum(th.my_gross_amount) my_gross_amount,
                         mycase
                   from mySch.trans_his th
                   join mySch.fund f on f.fund = th.fund
                   group by contact_id, th.created_dt, mycase) 
         where rownum < 4 ) a
    group by contact_id, created_dt
    ) as DetailNotes
from mySch.trans_his t
```

MS SQL query that I have converted

```
select 
      (select STUFF((
                SELECT ', '+ mycase 
                from (select TOP(3) th.CONTACT_ID,
                                    th.created_dt,
                                    sum(th.my_gross_amount) my_gross_amount,
                                    mycase
                       from mySch.dbo.trans_his th
                       join mySch.dbo.fund f on f.fund = th.fund
                       group by contact_id, th.created_dt, mycase)subQueryA
                Where subQueryA.my_gross_amount = subQueryB.my_gross_amount FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1, '') 
        from (select TOP (3) th.CONTACT_ID,
                             th.created_dt,
                             sum(th.my_gross_amount) my_gross_amount,
                             mycase
               from mySch.dbo.trans_his th
               join mySch.dbo.fund f on f.fund = th.fund
               group by contact_id, th.created_dt, mycase) subQueryB
        group by contact_id, created_dt, my_gross_amount
        ) as DetailNotes
from mySch.dbo.trans_his t
```

The same query takes a few seconds in Oracle but takes forever in sql server. Not sure if this is the best possible way to convert listAgg from oracle to SQl server.
And not sure if the SQL query is stuck in a loop.

> Oracle Version 12c
>   MS SQL Version 2016

Is there a better way to rewrite this query in SQL server?

Used the Following link to convert ListAgg function

[ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

UPDATE:

trans_his table details

```
trans_id    varchar2(20)            
firm_id varchar2(20)    
fund varchar2(20)
contact_id  varchar2(20)            
trade_cl    varchar2(2)         
my_gross_amount number(15,2)        
created_dt  date
```

fund table details

```
fund    varchar2(20)                
mycase  varchar2(100)       
start_date  date    
end_date    date
created_by  varchar2(20)        
created_dt  date
```

Comment: It looks like there are only two tables involved here? But there are around 6-7 queries going on. I can't even begin to decipher where this is attempting to do but I can say with certainty that is could be written better for sql server. Can you post the ddl of those two tables, some sample data and what you expect as output? For ideas on how to put this together see this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The equivalent method is `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server 2017. What you are trying to do here is emulate `WITHIN GROUP` in previous versions, not just `STRING_AGG`. None of the aggregation techniques was created with that in mind.

Comment: A possible exception is the SQLCLR technique. You can specify an ordering without a performance penalty as long as you don't create very big strings. Aaron Bertrand has written many articles on string aggregation and describes all techniques, including [the XML technique you used here and the use of a SQLCLR aggregate](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation)

Comment: I would suggest to [edit] your question and provide sample data as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) and desired results. This will allow for people familiar with SQL Server but not Oracle to answer your question.