# How to get a comma seperated list of datetimes in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with dates and names. Dates are datetime, and Name is nvarchar(50)
It's like this:

```
ID   | Name   | Date
1    | Joe    | 12.12.2012.
2    | Joe    | 15.12.2013.
```

How do I get a output like this:

```
ID   | Name   | Date
1    | Joe    | 12.12.2012.; 15.12.2013.
```

I know I can get this with stuff for xml, but then the Date column is nvarchar and I need to preserve a datetime for Date column. Is it possible?

Comment: Hello, maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: @ F.Lazarescu As I mentioned, if I use a xml and stuff, it converts a column to varchar, and I need to maintain the datetime data type.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't pay attention to that. You can't have a date column with anything that it's not a date ... and the string that you want as output, it's a string .. so the answer is no

Comment: As @F.Lazarescu says, combining dates into a single column and maintaining their type is not possible. You could look at using a `PIVOT` which could produce multiple _Date_ columns per unique _Name_.

Answer (score 1):

First, your data has `string` type as appears, perhaps you are looking for dates in `datetime` or only `date`.

If so, then you can use `concat()`:

```
select t.name,
       stuff( (select concat(';', convert(date, t1.[date], 103))
               from table t1
               where t.name = t1.name
               for xml path('')), 1,1, ''
              ) as Date
from table t
group by t.name;
```