# Column into Array Or Comma Delimited List in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Does t-sql have this possibility like oracle does?:
How would I grab a column from a table and put it into an array concisely?
If not ARRAY, then maybe a comma delimited list....  My data type is string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. Also, include the specific version tag in your question. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Please provide some input sample with the expected output. And please tag your question with the appropriate RDBMS, `[sql-server]` is not enugh, please add the version.

Comment: i can't believe this was downvoted.  There is an AWESOME answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another example of how you can do a comma delimited value.  Will work in SQL Version 2008 R2 and up:

```
    DECLARE @TestData TABLE
        (
            [ListItem] NVARCHAR(100)
        );

    --Declared as blank since leaving NULL will result in a final NULL value.
    DECLARE @DelimitedString NVARCHAR(500) = '';

    INSERT INTO @TestData (
                              [ListItem]
                          )
    VALUES ( N'ListItem1' )
         , ( N'ListItem2' )
         , ( N'ListItem3' );

    --puts the result set into @DelimitedString
    SELECT @DelimitedString = @DelimitedString + [ListItem] + N','
    FROM   @TestData;

    --Remove trailing comma
    SET @DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(
                                        @DelimitedString
                                      , 1
                                      , LEN(@DelimitedString) - 1
                                    );
    SELECT @DelimitedString;
```

Comment: AWESOME answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could brute-force it with a cursor ...

```
declare mycsv cursor for
select col1 from table1

declare @curItem nvarchar(max)
    , @csvList nvarchar(255)

select @curItem = ''
    , @csvList = ''
open mycsv

fetch next from mycsv into @curItem

while @@fetch_status = 0    
begin
    select @csvList = @csvList + @curItem + ','
    fetch next from mycsv into @curItem
end

close mycsv
deallocate mycsv

select @csvList
```

... then trim off the trailing comma.

Wish I could think of something more elegant.

Comment: You really, really don't want to use a cursor in SQL. Cusors are a last resort kind of thing - they are ugly, the work terribly slow, and they take way too much resources. using the regular `stuff` with `for xml` for older versions, or `string_agg` for 2017 is the way to go if you want to create a delimited list from rows, but I'm not even sure that's what the OP wants...

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but that is mean. I voted back up.  This is not the answer I was looking for, but I will accept it, because I don't think its really possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you're looking for but let's say you wanted a comma-delimited list of customer ids by customer last name. Something like:

```
lastName, customerIDs
Smith     2,4,6,9,27
Jones     3,10,16,20

select lastname, (select cast(customerID as varchar(15))+',' from customers x where x.lastname=c.lastname for xml path('')) customerIDs 
from customers c
```