# Cache SQL query to create 1 row from multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching, multiple-columns

I have the below record and would like to create 1 row record. 
I tried STUFF, FOR XML PATH and did not work

```
+-----------+-------+---------+
| CLIENT_ID | Event | DX_Code |
+-----------+-------+---------+
|        54 |     5 | F45.72  |
|        54 |     5 | X45.34  |
|        54 |     5 | M98.32  |
+-----------+-------+---------+
```

Output = 54, 5, F45.72 X45.34 M98.32

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: you have to use pivot in sql

Comment: This is pulling from Cache DB using Cache SQL syntax , I have tried using PIVOT SQL and is not acceptable Cache SQL syntax.

Comment: This should be a standard [LISTAGG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver) duplicate, but per your description the standard answers won't work.  What, exactly, is going wrong?  Is it returning the wrong values?  Is it throwing an error?  Is it not finishing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `STUFF()` with `FOR XML PATH('')` as

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([CLIENT_ID] int, [Event] int, [DX_Code] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([CLIENT_ID], [Event], [DX_Code])
VALUES
    (54, 5, 'F45.72'),
    (54, 5, 'X45.34'),
    (54, 5, 'M98.32')
;

SELECT DISTINCT T1.[CLIENT_ID],
                T1.[Event],
                STUFF(
                        (
                          SELECT ',' + T2.[DX_Code] 
                          FROM T T2
                          WHERE T2.[CLIENT_ID] = T1.[CLIENT_ID]
                                AND T2.[Event] = T1.[Event]
                          FOR XML PATH ('')
                        ) , 1, 1, ''
                    ) Result
FROM T T1;
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error when using that query with STUFF FOR XML PATH

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the expected result

```
SELECT      CAST(t1.CLIENT_ID AS VARCHAR) + ','+ CAST(t1.Event AS VARCHAR)+ ','+
            STUFF((    SELECT ' ' + t2.DX_Code AS [text()]

                        FROM #temp t2
                        WHERE
                        t2.CLIENT_ID = t1.CLIENT_ID
                        and       t2.Event = t1.Event
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '' )

            AS OutputText
FROM  #temp t1
GROUP BY t1.CLIENT_ID,t1.Event
```

Output:

```
54,5,F45.72 X45.34 M98.32
```