# using recursive function to simulate group_concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, recursion, sql-server-2012

I have a table like

```
ID NAME
1  STALIN
2  MERWIN
1  AMALA
1 RAYON
```

i want the out as

```
ID NAME
1 STALIN,AMALA,RAYON
2 MERWIN
```

How can do this using recursive function

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc) that you are using.

Comment: Yes..Using SQL server recursive function

Comment: which version of SQL-Server ..?

Comment: @barbaros: SQL 2012

Comment: you can refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: @barbaros: i want use recursive function to achieve this.

Comment: There you can see a sample with `Common Table Expression`

Comment: you need a column that specifies the desired order for deterministic results

Comment: Why does it matter if you use a recursive function?  What exactly would you consider to be a "recursive function" in SQL, because there's nothing officially called that, so if we're to use your made-up terms, you should at least define them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `XML Path`

```
SELECT ID, NAME = 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + NAME
       FROM your_table b 
       WHERE b.ID = a.ID 
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM your_table a
GROUP BY ID
```

[Live Demo](https://rextester.com/GWZUW52864) 
[image]

[Follow this link](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-performance-myth-busters/) and see the case 3. it explains why to use XML path over recursive cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` to get the result:

for example:

```
DECLARE @EXAMPLE TABLE (ID int, NAME nvarchar(10))
INSERT @EXAMPLE VALUES (1,'STALIN'),(2,'MERWIN'),(1,'AMALA'),(1,'RAYON')

SELECT
    ID,
    SUBSTRING(NAME,0,LEN(NAME)) AS NAME
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT 
            T1.ID,
            STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '' + t2.NAME + ','
                    FROM @EXAMPLE T2
                    WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,0,'') NAME
        FROM @EXAMPLE t1) AS info
```