# How to get SQL query result as one row comma delimited and with single quotes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get result set of a SQL query as one row with comma delimiter and single quotes wrapped around each column value. For e.g. output of SQL query should be
'A1','A2','A3','A4','A5',......'An'

I was able to achieve this using LISTAGG, but for ORacle DB and too had a size limitation. So I am looking for something which doesn't have this kind of size limitation and also for SQL server. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This certainly doesn't look like SQL Server code to me.

Comment: That error isn't a SQL Server error, and the syntax isn't valid T-SQL (`||` isn't used in T-SQL, it's the `+` operator to concatenate). Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server here?

Comment: I apologize, I should have specified that I have used LISTAGG against oracle DB, and now I am working against SQL server and that's where I need to have the output string in one row with single quotes and comma delimited. I have updated the question too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get following query to work for me:

```
Select SUBSTRING( 
( 
SELECT ',' +''''+ ColName +'''' AS 'data()' 
FROM TableName FOR XML PATH('') 
), 2 , 999999) As DCN
```

Answer (score 0):

`LISTAGG` is an oracle function.
Please see this stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

use `STRING_AGG`

```
select STRING_AGG(FieldB, ',')
from yourtable t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
The SELECT ',' + 'column name here' from 'the table'  for xml path (''), type
```

or in SQL Server 2017 and later, STRING_AGG('column name here',',') makes this task much cleaner and easier.