# Merging duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck at the following problem.
I made a sql select and get sth. like that:

```
invoiceid  orderid
1233       28
1234       29
1234       30
1234       31
1234       32
1234       33
```

Now I wanna merge those invoiceid to this:

```
invoiceid  orderid
1233       28
1234       29,30,31,32,33
```

MS-SQL 2014

Comment: Found an other post about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver It's working.

Comment: This is a bad idea; keep your data normalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For older versions of SQL, you will need to do some trickeration.

```
SELECT invoiceid,
      STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + orderid 
        FROM your_table
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') AS orderid
    WHERE your_table.inoiceid = final.invoiceid
FROM your_table final
GROUP BY invoiceid
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017+, you would use `string_agg()`:

```
select invoiceid, string_agg(orderid, ',') within group (order by order_id)
frmo t
group by invoiceid;
```

Comment: Forgotten to add my mssql server version: 14
there string_agg() isn't build in.
searching google for an alternative...