# group Concat in sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have query like this

```sql
select PersonalCode , TransferUnitTitle 
from Qry_TransferHistory join vw_MasterSimple m On m.Emp_Num = PersonalCode
```

and result is:

```
PersonalCode     TransferUnitTitle
  981203030             A
  981203030             B
```

and I want to change this query in **SQL Server 2014** to make this result (**`STRING_AGG` is not working** ):

```
PersonalCode    TransferUnitTitle
  981203030            A,B
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Comment: Why is `STRING_AGG()` not working?

Comment: Because the OP is using SQL Server 2014, @BJones .

Comment: @BJones Because it was introduced in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Whoops. Forgot it was 17.

Answer (score -2):

Create a function which will take input of PersonalCode and will select the TransferUnitTitle and iterate through cursor and store this in a string by comma separated variable. And return this string.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's an idea, and it suggests the worst way of doing so; a `CURSOR`.

Comment: Larnu, come with better idea/resolution rather than putting just comments.

Comment: I did, I marked this as a duplicate. Would you have preferred I downvoted anonymously? This fact that this is a low quality answer (it doesn't actually provide an answer) is the reason for my downvote however. my point on the `CURSOR` was additional. SQL isn't a programming language; don't treat it like one. Iterative tasks are inherently slow in them.