# SQL inner join and group by to get comma separated values

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have following three tables, from which I would like to get a specific result

TableA

```
key1    key2
-------------
121     4
131     4
141     5
151     3
161     3
171     6
181     6
191     6
...     ...
```

TableB:

```
key1    key3
-------------
121     1001
131     1111
141     1111
151     1222
161     1222
171     1234
181     1001
191     1111
...     ...
```

TableC:

```
key3    key4
-------------
1001    "aa"
1111    "gg"
1222    "hh"
1234    "jj"
...     ...
```

I want a SQL query (which could use inner join) to give me the following result:

```
key2    key4
-------------------------
3       "hh"
4       "aa", "gg"
5       "gg"
6       "aa", "gg", "jj"
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_agg()`:

```
select t1.key2, string_agg(t3.key4, ',') key4
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.key1 = t1.key1
inner join table3 t3 on t3.key3 = t1.key3
group by t1.key2
```

Comment: error - 'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: @vjjj: are you sure that you are running this against a Posgres database?

Comment: Its SQL server, will change the tags, my bad!

Comment: @vjjj: string aggregation functions are vendor-specific... Which version of SQL Server? 2017 has `string_agg()`.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: @vjjj: in this version you need something like `for xml path`. You can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below SQL query:

```
SELECT key2, string_agg(key4, ",")
FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (key1) JOIN TableC USING (key3)
GROUP BY key2
```