# SQL query inner join and group by to get comma separated value without using string_agg()

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have following three tables, from which I would like to ge a specific result

```
TableA -
key1    key2
121     4
131     4
141     5
151     3
161     3
171     6
181     6
191     6
...     ...


TableB -
key1    key3
121     1001
131     1111
141     1111
151     1222
161     1222
171     1234
181     1001
191     1111
...     ...


TableC -
key3    key4
1001    "aa"
1111    "gg"
1222    "hh"
1234    "jj"
...     ...
```

I want a SQL query (which could use inner join) to give me the following result :-

```
New_Table -
key2    key4
3       "hh"
4       "aa", "gg"
5       "gg"
6       "aa", "gg", "jj"
```

I got an answer from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838624/sql-inner-join-and-group-by-to-get-comma-separated-values) with the following query :-

```
select t1.key2, string_agg(t3.key4, ',') key4
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.key1 = t1.key1
inner join table3 t3 on t3.key3 = t1.key3
group by t1.key2
```

But my SQL server does not allow string_agg() function!

How can I replace string_agg() with its equivalent form for older version of SQL server?

SQL - Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Why have the mysql tag for the question then? Since you say this is for SQL Server.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that!

Comment: "older version of SQL Server" doesn't really specify the version we need to know, does it? :P

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string\_agg for sql server pre 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-pre-2017)

Answer (score 0):

For the uninitiated, grouped concatenation is when you want to take multiple rows of data and compress them into a single string (usually with delimiters like commas, tabs, or spaces). Some might call this a "horizontal join."
There have been many ways to solve this problem over the years:

Scalar UDF, Common Language Runtime (CLR), Recursive CTE, Cursor

Have a read here: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation

Also have a read here:

[How to make a query with group_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)