# SQL Query - Copy Data into One Field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database and I am writing a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Consignments
INNER JOIN OrderDetail
      ON Consignments.consignment_id = OrderDetail.consignment_id
INNER JOIN UserReferences
      ON OrderDetail.record_id = UserReferences.record_id
WHERE Consignments.despatch_date = '2020-04-23'
```

Within the first column is:consignment_id [this is from the Consignments table]In the final column is:senders_reference [this is from the UserReferences table]

Now - the issue I have is - that when I am running the query to pick up all consignments for a particular date - it is displaying multiple rows (with duplicated consignment_id) when there are multiple senders references within the database.

If there is one senders reference number - then there is only 1 row.

This makes sense - because within the front-end for the database the user can enter 1 or more senders references.

Now - what I would like to do is to amend my query for the resulting data to only display 1 row for all consignments and if there are multiple senders reference numbers - to have them within the one field, separated by commas.

Is this doable from the query stage?

Or if not - after export, is it possible to develop a bat file to do the same thing?

For reference - this is what I mean - this is the result I am getting at the moment:
[image: data i'm getting at the moment]
This is what I need:

[image: what i need]

Comment: Update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use older style with the help of `for xml` :

```
select t.consignment_id,
       stuff((select ', ' +convert(varchar(255), t1.sender_reference)
              from table t1 
              where t1.consignment_id = t.consignment_id
              for xml path('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as senders_reference
from (select distinct consignment_id from table t) t;
```

Edit : You can use `CTE` :

```
with cte as (
     <your query>
)
select t.consignment_id,
       stuff((select ', ' +convert(varchar(255), t1.sender_reference)
              from cte t1 
              where t1.consignment_id = t.consignment_id
              for xml path('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as senders_reference
from (select distinct consignment_id from cte t) t;
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm actually with this database I'm on Server 2008 R2... concat does not work on this...

Comment: @Rick. . .Use operator `+`.

Comment: this is bringing up errors:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.

Comment: @Rick. . . You need to replace `table-name` in place of `table`.

Comment: There are a couple of other tables which need to be joined
INNER JOIN OrderDetail
      ON Consignments.consignment_id = OrderDetail.consignment_id
INNER JOIN UserReferences
      ON OrderDetail.record_id = UserReferences.record_id

Comment: I am trying to add a few other columns into the query - but its coming up an error when i add them to the two select clauses - The multi-part identifier "OrderHeader.receiver_index" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to use the `STRING_AGG` function.

This answer covers it nicely 
[ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Comment: sorry just noticed that this database is on Server 2008 R2