# How to replace STRING_AGG and CONCAT in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, legacy

I use MS SQL Server 2008 and this server version doesn't support some helpful functions like `CONCAT` and `STRING_AGG`, but they are really needful in my work.
What variants can I have for replacing those functions in MS SQL Server 2008?

**IMPORTANT!** I have no possibility to update Server to newer version.

Code for better understanding:

```
SELECT Pt.ImagePath, STRING_AGG(Pt.DamageData, '') DamageData 
FROM @PreTable AS Pt 
GROUP BY ImagePath 
ORDER BY DamageData
```

Comment: Upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server that does. 2008 is completely out of support so upgrading is by far the best solution here. You say you don't have an option, but if that is true, you should be telling us why; as there are hardly ever any scenarios where you can never upgrade.

Comment: `STRING_AGG` can be handled with the XML support from gotqn's answer. `CONCAT` can be handled by converting all column types to a text data type and "adding them up". `select concat('abc', '-', 123);` equals `select 'abc' + '-' + cast(123 as nvarchar(10));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSoruce AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ImagePath
    FROM @PreTable
)
SELECT DS.ImagePath
      ,C.DamageData
FROM DataSoruce DS
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT '' + Pt.DamageData
    FROM @PreTable P
    WHERE P.ImagePath = DS.ImagePath
    FOR XML PATH('')
) C (DamageData);
```

Comment: @AndreyVaulin, see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax/207380#207380) for a detailed explanation of the XML PATH technique and additional considerations.

Comment: Why would you leave in the `'' +`?  The answer should also use `outer apply`, to be equivalent to the OP's code.

Comment: Without the `''+` you will get `<DamageData>...</DamageData>` concatenate tags. We are using `DISTINCT ImagePath` in the `CTE`, so there will be match for sure. No need to use `OUTER APPLY`.