# Roll up multiple rows into one when joining in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, Foo

```
ID | Name
-----------
1  | ONE
2  | TWO
3  | THREE
```

And another, Bar:

```
ID | FooID | Value
------------------
1  | 1     | Alpha
2  | 1     | Alpha
3  | 1     | Alpha
4  | 2     | Beta
5  | 2     | Gamma
6  | 2     | Beta
7  | 3     | Delta
8  | 3     | Delta
9  | 3     | Delta
```

I would like a query that joins these tables, returning one row for each row in Foo, rolling up the 'value' column from Bar. I can get back the first Bar.Value for each FooID:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo f OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM Bar WHERE FooId = f.ID
) AS b
```

Giving:

```
ID | Name  | Value
---------------------
1  | ONE   | Alpha
2  | TWO   | Beta
3  | THREE | Delta
```

But that's not what I want, and I haven't been able to find a variant that will bring back a rolled up value, that is the single Bar.Value if it is the same for each corresponding Foo, or a static string something like '(multiple)' if not:

```
ID | Name  | Value
---------------------
1  | ONE   | Alpha
2  | TWO   | (multiple)
3  | THREE | Delta
```

I have found some solutions that would bring back concatenated values (albeit not very elegant) 'Alpha' Alpha, Alpha', 'Beta, Gamma, Beta' &c, but that's not what I want either.

Comment: You can try using string_agg if your SQL Server versino is at least 2017 as mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver
For your query it could be : 
Select Foo.Id, Foo.Name, string_agg(Bar.Value,'')
From Foo, Bar
Where Foo.ID = Bar.FooID
Group by Foo.ID, Foo.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method, using a a `CASE` expression and *assuming* that `[Value]` cannot have a value of `NULL`:

```sql
WITH Foo AS
    (SELECT *
     FROM (VALUES (1, 'ONE'),
                  (2, 'TWO'),
                  (3, 'THREE')) V (ID, [Name])),
Bar AS
    (SELECT *
     FROM (VALUES (1, 1, 'Alpha'),
                  (2, 1, 'Alpha'),
                  (3, 1, 'Alpha'),
                  (4, 2, 'Beta'),
                  (5, 2, 'Gamma'),
                  (6, 2, 'Beta'),
                  (7, 3, 'Delta'),
                  (8, 3, 'Delta'),
                  (9, 3, 'Delta')) V (ID, FooID, [Value]))
SELECT F.ID,
       F.[Name],
       CASE COUNT(DISTINCT B.[Value]) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(B.Value) ELSE '(Multiple)' END AS [Value]
FROM Foo F
     JOIN Bar B ON F.ID = B.FooID
GROUP BY F.ID,
         F.[Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below:

```
SELECT F.ID, F.Name, (case when B.Value like '%,%' then '(Multiple)' else B.Value end) as Value
FROM Foo F
outer apply
(
select SUBSTRING(( 
                    SELECT distinct  ', '+  isnull(Value,',') FROM Bar WHERE FooId = F.ID
                    FOR XML PATH('') 
                    ), 2 , 9999) as Value
) as B
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked, as the value `(multiple)` is desired and not a list of all values.