# SQL Server : need to pivot some columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have an HR System in SQL Server 2016. I need to build a result set (table) from an employee table (shown below). The idea is to identify all the names an employee has had and pivot that into a single column. The most common scenario is a person who marries and then changes her last name.

```
emp_number  emp_fname   emp_lname
----------------------------------
1            Marilyn    Jones
2            Joan       Smith
3            Jean       Robinson
4            Shelia     Hayes
4            Shelia     Mclean
4            Shelia     Taylor
5            Heather    Iles
6            Lisa       Norman
7            Andrea     Plant
7            Andrea     Clancy
```

I need to have one row for each emp_number. In that row, if there are multiple records for an emp number, pivot the emp_fname and emp_lname, concatenate these fields, and then write to single record. The table below is what I am aiming for

```
emp_number  emp_name_concat
-----------------------------
1           Marilyn Jones
2           Joan Smith
3           Jean Robinson
4           Shelia Hayes , Shelia Mclean , Shelia Taylor 
5           Heather Iles
6           Lisa Norman 
7           Andrea Plant, Andrea Clancy
```

I'm looking at the pivot examples, but they seem to show scenarios where the number of rows to be pivoted is known. Theoretically, a person can change their last name any number of times. And, all rows do not need to be pivoted.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: You can refer to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver for all available methods.

Comment: This worked Great. Thank you for this,

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a 2016 version you can't use `STRING_AGG()`... Perhaps the following will work.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (emp_number INT, emp_fname NVARCHAR(100), emp_lname NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Table VALUES
(1,'Marilyn'    ,'Jones'),
(2,'Joan'       ,'Smith'),
(3,'Jean'       ,'Robinson'),
(4,'Shelia'     ,'Hayes'),
(4,'Shelia'     ,'Mclean'),
(4,'Shelia'     ,'Taylor'),
(5,'Heather'    ,'Iles'),
(6,'Lisa'       ,'Norman'),
(7,'Andrea'     ,'Plant'),
(7,'Andrea'     ,'Clancy')



SELECT DISTINCT
  t.emp_number,
  STUFF
  ((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.emp_fname + ' ' + t2.emp_lname
      FROM @Table t2
      WHERE t2.emp_number = t.emp_number
      FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 2, N''
  ) AS emp_name_concat
FROM @Table t
ORDER BY t.emp_number;
```