# SQL query cast from a group

Tags: sql, group-by, casting

I'm trying to make a query whit a 'cast group by' - output.

But not quit sure how to tackle this or even to start (I think i need cast and group by but not sure).

I have some code below which hopefully explains what I'm trying to do.
Could somebody help me to make a query to have the correct output?

```
CREATE TABLE buyers
(
    id int,
    buyer_name varchar(20)
);
    
INSERT INTO buyers
VALUES (1, 'harry'), (2, 'zoe'), (3, 'rose');
    
CREATE TABLE grocery
(
    id int,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    id_buyers int
);
    
INSERT INTO grocery
VALUES (1, 'milk', 1), (2, 'milk', 1), (3, 'ham', 1), (4, 'bread', 2),
       (5, 'bread', 2), (6, 'bread', 2), (6, 'milk', 2), (7, 'milk', 2),
       (8, 'ham', 3);

CREATE TABLE wanted_output
(
    name VARCHAR(20),
    stuffed_lists VARCHAR(20)
);
    
INSERT INTO wanted_output
VALUES ('harry', '2x milk, 1x ham'), ('zoe', '3x bread, 2x milk'),
       ('rose', '1x ham ');
```

EDIT :
at this point I have this (not working):

```
    SELECT 
      buyers.buyer_name,
      COALESCE(
        STUFF(
          (SELECT ' , ' + 
                  CAST( grocery.name AS varchar(max)) 
          from grocery 
          where grocery.id_buyers = buyers.id 
          FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '' ),'') 
      
      AS wanted_output
    FROM buyers
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Comment: unfortunaly not quit, I'm not sure how to get the '1x' or '2x'

Comment: `group by grocery.name` then `cast(count(*) as varchar(4)) + 'x ' + grocery.name` then group it again on that result and use `string_agg`

Comment: string_agg group by is a little new to me, could you please provide a working example? I am not sure how to copple this cast group by togheter.

Comment: nvm version 2016 :( unfortanly is the function string_agg not introduced. Could somebody help me with a working example whitout string_agg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm afther some fideling :

```
    SELECT 
      buyers.buyer_name,
      COALESCE(
        STUFF(
          (SELECT ' , ' + cast(count(*) as varchar(4)) + ' x ' +
                  CAST( grocery.name AS varchar(max)) 
          from grocery 
          where grocery.id_buyers = buyers.id 
          group by grocery.name
          FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '' ),'') 
      
      AS wanted_output
    FROM buyers
```