# Returning a comma delimited list from left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query below:

```sql
SELECT parentpg.page_name + ' ('
       + Cast(parentpg.page_id AS VARCHAR(10))
       + ')'                                   AS ParentPgNm,
       pg.page_name + ' ('
       + Cast(pg.page_id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' AS 'PageNm',
       CASE
         WHEN secrole.role_name IS NULL THEN
         cP.first_name + ' ' + CP.last_name +
         ' (Person '
         + Cast(CP.person_id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
         ELSE secrole.role_name + ' (Role '
              + Cast(secrole.role_id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
       END                                     AS RolePerson,
       CASE perm.operation_type
         WHEN 0 THEN 'View'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Edit'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Edit Security'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Edit Modules'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Edit Notes'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Approve'
         ELSE '??'
       END                                     AS 'PrivName'
FROM   [dbo].[port_portal_page] pg
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[port_portal_page] parentpg
                    ON pg.parent_page_id = parentpg.page_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN secu_permission perm
                    ON pg.page_id = perm.object_key
                       AND perm.object_type = 1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN secu_role secrole
                    ON perm.subject_key = secrole.role_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN core_person CP
                    ON perm.subject_key = CP.person_id
WHERE  pg.page_id = 244
```

[Output Pic - Sorry I can't imbed yet as I am a new user]

```
ParentPgNm     PageNm           RolePerson                  PrivName
Sports (99)    Schedule (244)   Administrators (Role 2)     View
Sports (99)    Schedule (244)   Administrators (Role 2)     Edit
Sports (99)    Schedule (244)   Administrators (Role 2)     Approve
Sports (99)    Schedule (244)   Administrators (Role 2)     Edit Security
Sports (99)    Schedule (244)   Administrators (Role 2)     Edit Modules
Sports (99)    Schedule (244)   Admin (Role 60)             Approve
```

I would like to have the query return one row per "RolePerson" and the the PrivName column be a comma separated value list. I am using SQL Server 2014.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could check this out [ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver).
There was some example for SQL Server <= 2016

Comment: Thanks but I just can't get the syntax right inside my query. I have tried for hours with Stuff and Coalesce and other solutions.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems to have worked. Written based on the example in the link I previously added. Please check. The first select should be replaced with your query.

```
WITH CTE_TableName AS (
    SELECT ParentPgNm, PageNm, RolePerson, PrivName
    FROM DATA 
)
SELECT 
    t0.ParentPgNm, 
    t0.PageNm, 
    t0.RolePerson, 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + t1.PrivName
        FROM CTE_TableName t1
        WHERE t1.ParentPgNm = t0.ParentPgNm 
          AND t1.PageNm = t0.PageNm 
          AND t1.RolePerson = t0.RolePerson
        ORDER BY t1.PrivName
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, LEN(','), '') AS PrivNames
FROM CTE_TableName t0
GROUP BY t0.ParentPgNm, t0.PageNm, t0.RolePerson;
```

Comment: To prevent XML escaping, use `....FOR XML PATH('')).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1....`