# SQL Count with Table

Tags: sql, bq

I have one table:

| ID | Account |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 44 |
| 3 | 22 |

So lots of duplicates as you can see. I need to basically write a query that does 2 things:

1. Matches the separate IDs with linked accounts -- so 1, 3 are 22
2. Counts the number of times they link -- so in the case above, twice.

Edit:

My desired result is the number of times Account 22 is linked with an ID and the list of those IDs.

Comment: please try to edit your question with the output you are looking for.  like a specific row of results instead of the English description.  also, have you tried any SQL - what error did you get?

Comment: which db you are really using?

Answer (score 2):

Tested: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6d84edba642dcb057441ea15540e8da4

If you have an analytic function available a simple group by, and count with the analytic count()

```
SELECT ID, Account, Count(ID) over (Partition by Account) as CNT
FROM OneTable
GROUP BY ID, Account
ORDER BY Account, ID
```

The analytic basically says, For each account return a count of the distinct IDs.  the outer group by returns a list of ID's and accounts

So results would look something like: (Assuming I did it right)

```
ID  Account CNT
1   22      2
3   22      2
2   44      1


DDL Sample: SOURCE
SELECT ID, Account, Count(ID) over (Partition by Account) as CNT
FROM (Values (1 , 22),
(1, 22),
(2, 44),
(3, 22)) X (ID, Account)
GROUP BY ID, Account
ORDER BY Account, ID
```

Comment: Note: original version and a count(Distinct ID) which is invalid in an analytic.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a "group-by", "count()" (aggregate function), an "alias" to the same table and a "sub-query":

- group-by: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
- count(): https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp
- alias: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    master.ACCOUNT,
    master.COUNT(*) AS number
FROM
    table master
WHERE 
    distinct ID IN (SELECT distinct ID
                    FROM table t1, table t2
                    WHERE t1.account = t2.account)
GROUP-BY
    master.ACCOUNT;
```

SQL result:

| Account | number |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 2 |
| 44 | 1 |

For the IDs you would have to use something equivalent to Oracle "ListAGG" - but that depends on the database you are using.

Is it best to follow these instructions?

[ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Also take care of duplicates in a table, this should generally be avoided  → Maybe you have a auto-increment primary key (pk) for that table - something like this:

| pk | ID | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 01 | 22 |

If you need to update the same ID, use a "MERGE" (update or insert) -
The syntax for a "merge"-query also depends on the used database (e.g. Oracle SQL Server ...).