# Same Id Different product from SQL output in one line using PHP

Tags: php, sql

Same Id but multiple different product in SQL.
Data should be retrieved from SQL and Output should be shortened to one line for each ID using PHP.

EXAMPLE:

SQL

| ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Laptop |
| 001 | Monitor |
| 001 | Speaker |
| 002 | Phone |
| 003 | Other Services |

Expected Output

PHP

| ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Laptop, Monitor, Speaker |
| 002 | Phone, Case |
| 003 | Other Services |

MY CODE

```
$sql = "SELECT id, product From Stock";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $id[] = $row["id"];
        $product[] = $row["product"];
}

$max_id = count($id);
$duplicate_id = array();

for($i=0; $i<$max_id;$i++){

    $duplicate_m[$id[$i]] = $id[$i] = $product[$i];
}
print_r($duplicate_m);
```

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
[001] => Laptop
[002] => Phone
[003] => Other Services
```

Comment: what format column is the ID column?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
for($i=0; $i<$max_id;$i++){
  if(!isset($duplicate_m[$id[$i]])){
    $duplicate_m[$id[$i]] = $id[$i] = $product[$i];
  }else{
    $duplicate_m[$id[$i]] .= ", {$product[$i]}";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use associative array, and override the values of the `$duplicate_m` array.
You should check if key exists, and then save the element. Also, you should use multidimensional array.
So

```
for($i=0; $i<$max_id;$i++){
   if(!isset($duplicate_m[$id[$i]])){
       duplicate_m[$id[$i]] = [];
       duplicate_m[$id[$i]][] = $product[$i];
   } else {
       duplicate_m[$id[$i]][] = $product[$i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of sql server, you can use `string_agg` function

```
$sql = "select id, string_agg(product, ',') from Stock group by id"
```

Should return your data in the way you want, without transformations in PHP code.

For other versions you can check this other question in SO with the needed code =>
[ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the product to an array with id index in this way:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    array_push($id[$row["id"]], $row["product"]);
}
```