# DISTINCT on INNER JOIN table

Tags: sql, inner-join, distinct

I'm trying to cast the not distinct table as one so the id table is distinct

I wrote a query to get roles from users but I want the emails to be distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (users.id), (roles.name)
FROM users_roles 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users_roles.user_id
INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = users_roles.role_id
```

The data I get back looks like this

```
+---------+--------------+
| ID      | Name         | 
+---------+--------------+
| 1       | Student      | 
| 2       | Admin        | 
| 3       | LBC          | 
| 2       | LBC          | 
| 4       | Examinator   |
| 5       | PO           | 
+---------+--------------+
```

The data I was hoping to get back looks like this so I would like to cast the names table as one if this is even possible

```
+---------+--------------+
| ID      | Name         | 
+---------+--------------+
| 1       | Student      | 
| 2       | Admin, LBC   | 
| 3       | LBC          | 
| 4       | Examinator   |
| 5       | PO           | 
+---------+--------------+
```

I'm using MySQL for my database

Comment: You are looking for string concatenate aggregation. Most of the RDMS have such build-in function.

Comment: I guess, you need names to be distinct, not e-mails. And please also specify DB you use.

Comment: The terminology you are after is not "distinct", you are trying to group and aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle, you can use `LISTAGG` for this:

```sql
select id, LISTAGG(name, ',')
  from (
        SELECT DISTINCT users.id, roles.name
        FROM users_roles 
        INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users_roles.user_id
        INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = users_roles.role_id
    )
 group by id
```

Here for unique ids names will be concatenated by comma.

Demo can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/c3vomld_).

If you use another dbms, solution would be similar but with other function (like `group_concat` for MySQL or `string_agg` for PostgreSQL or BigQuery). Most of them listed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348687/21363224).

EDIT, For MySQL:

```sql
 select b.id, group_concat(b.name ORDER BY b.name SEPARATOR ',') AS g
  from (
        SELECT DISTINCT users.id, roles.name
        FROM users_roles 
        INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users_roles.user_id
        INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = users_roles.role_id ) b
group by id
```

Demo for MySQL [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jOFdOKBz).

Comment: Im using mysql, sorry for not specifying

Comment: @zweqmeister, added query for MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select b.id, group_concat(b.name ORDER BY b.name SEPARATOR ',') AS Name
  from (
        SELECT DISTINCT u.id, r.name
        FROM users_roles ur
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = ur.user_id
        INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.role_id ) b
group by id
```